# How to create an EAV entity?

Tags: module, admin, magento-1, eav

**How to create an EAV entity?**

This is a question that pops up a lot on the web. There are some good blog articles that explain how to do that, but none of them are satisfying for me.
So I decided to a self-answered question and explain how I do it ... and it seems to work.

There is a lot of code in here. In order to read correctly sort the answers by 'oldest'.

Comment: great elaborate answer

Comment: great answer!!, But I was looking for help in creating EAV Entity in magento 2, any help will be appreciable!

Comment: @SheshgiriAnvekar you and me both my friend.

Comment: @Marius are you able to find the answer for this in M2 if so can you please paste same for M2 also here it will help lot really.

Comment: @Zaheerabbas. I have't created any EAV entities so far in Magento 2. Sorry

Answer (score 32, accepted):

**Part 1**

For the purpose of this demo I'm going to create a module, let's name it `Easylife_News` that contains an entity named `Article`.
The module comes with complete CRUD code for backend, including the section for managing attributes, and some simple frontend listing and view page for each article. It also ads a menu item in the top menu to the listing of articles.
It also contains URL rewrites, RSS feed and breadcrumbs for frontend.
This entity will have 4 attributes: `Title, Short Description, Description, Publish Date` in addition to the system ones (`created_at`, `updated_at`, `status`, `in_rss`, `url_key`).
The module should contain the following files.

`app/etc/module/Easylife_News.xml` - the declaration module:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Easylife_News>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
            <depends>
                <Mage_Catalog /><!-- some classes extend one class from the catalog module to avoid duplicating it -->
             </depends>
        </Easylife_News>
    </modules>
</config>
```

`app/code/local/Easylife/News/etc/config.xml` - the configuration file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Easylife_News>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </Easylife_News>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <resources>
            <easylife_news_setup>
                <setup>
                    <module>Easylife_News</module>
                    <class>Easylife_News_Model_Resource_Setup</class>
                </setup>
            </easylife_news_setup>
        </resources>
        <blocks>
            <easylife_news>
                <class>Easylife_News_Block</class>
            </easylife_news>
        </blocks>
        <helpers>
            <easylife_news>
                <class>Easylife_News_Helper</class>
            </easylife_news>
        </helpers>
        <models>
            <easylife_news>
                <class>Easylife_News_Model</class>
                <resourceModel>easylife_news_resource</resourceModel>
            </easylife_news>
            <easylife_news_resource>
                <class>Easylife_News_Model_Resource</class>
                <entities>
                    <article>
                        <table>easylife_news_article</table>
                    </article>
                    <eav_attribute>
                        <table>easylife_news_eav_attribute</table>
                    </eav_attribute>
                </entities>
            </easylife_news_resource>
        </models>
        <events>
            <controller_front_init_routers><!-- event for custom router - url rewrites -->
                <observers>
                    <easylife_news>
                        <class>Easylife_News_Controller_Router</class>
                        <method>initControllerRouters</method>
                    </easylife_news>
                </observers>
            </controller_front_init_routers>
        </events>
    </global>
    <adminhtml>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <easylife_news>
                    <file>easylife_news.xml</file>
                </easylife_news>
            </updates>
        </layout>
        <translate>
            <modules>
                <Easylife_News>
                    <files>
                        <default>Easylife_News.csv</default>
                    </files>
                </Easylife_News>
            </modules>
        </translate>
        <global_search>
            <article>
                <class>easylife_news/adminhtml_search_article</class>
                <acl>easylife_news</acl>
            </article>
        </global_search>
    </adminhtml>
    <admin>
        <routers>
            <adminhtml>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <Easylife_News before="Mage_Adminhtml">Easylife_News_Adminhtml</Easylife_News>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </adminhtml>
        </routers>
    </admin>
    <frontend>
        <events>
            <page_block_html_topmenu_gethtml_before><!-- add link to top menu -->
                <observers>
                    <easylife_news>
                        <class>easylife_news/observer</class>
                        <method>addItemsToTopmenuItems</method>
                    </easylife_news>
                </observers>
            </page_block_html_topmenu_gethtml_before>
        </events>

        <routers>
            <easylife_news>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Easylife_News</module>
                    <frontName>news</frontName>
                </args>
            </easylife_news>
        </routers>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <easylife_news>
                    <file>easylife_news.xml</file>
                </easylife_news>
            </updates>
        </layout>
        <translate>
            <modules>
                <Easylife_News>
                    <files>
                        <default>Easylife_News.csv</default>
                    </files>
                </Easylife_News>
            </modules>
        </translate>
    </frontend>
    <default>
        <easylife_news>
            <article>
                <breadcrumbs>1</breadcrumbs>
                <url_prefix>article</url_prefix>
                <url_suffix>html</url_suffix>
                <rss>1</rss>
                <meta_title>Articles</meta_title>
            </article>
        </easylife_news>
    </default>
</config>
```

`app/code/local/Easylife/News/etc/adminhtml.xml` - the admin acl and menu file.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <acl>
        <resources>
            <admin>
                <children>
                    <system>
                        <children>
                            <config>
                                <children>
                                    <easylife_news translate="title" module="easylife_news">
                                        <title>News</title>
                                    </easylife_news>
                                </children>
                            </config>
                        </children>
                    </system>
                    <cms>
                        <children>
                            <easylife_news translate="title" module="easylife_news">
                                <title>News</title>
                                    <children>
                                        <article translate="title" module="easylife_news">
                                            <title>Article</title>
                                            <sort_order>0</sort_order>
                                        </article>
                                        <article_attributes translate="title" module="easylife_news">
                                            <title>Manage Article attributes</title>
                                            <sort_order>7</sort_order>
                                        </article_attributes>
                                    </children>
                                </easylife_news>
                            </children>
                        </cms>

                </children>
            </admin>
        </resources>
    </acl>
    <menu>
        <cms><!-- I added the admin menu under CMS. Feel free to move it. -->
            <children>
                <easylife_news translate="title" module="easylife_news">
                    <title>News</title>
                    <sort_order>17</sort_order>
                    <children>
                        <article translate="title" module="easylife_news">
                            <title>Article</title>
                            <action>adminhtml/news_article</action>
                            <sort_order>0</sort_order>
                        </article>
                        <article_attributes translate="title" module="easylife_news">
                            <title>Manage Article Attributes</title>
                            <action>adminhtml/news_article_attribute</action>
                            <sort_order>7</sort_order>
                        </article_attributes>
                    </children>
                </easylife_news>
            </children>
        </cms>

    </menu>
</config>
```

`app/code/local/Easylife/News/etc/system.xml` - the system configuration file. It allows you to manage a few settings like SEO for the articles list, breadcrumbs, RSS enable/disable, url prefix and suffix

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <tabs>
        <easylife translate="label" module="easylife_news">
            <label>News</label>
            <sort_order>2000</sort_order>
        </easylife>
    </tabs>
    <sections>
        <easylife_news translate="label" module="easylife_news">
            <class>separator-top</class>
            <label>News</label>
            <tab>easylife</tab>
            <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
            <sort_order>100</sort_order>
            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
            <groups>
                <article translate="label" module="easylife_news">
                    <label>Article</label>
                    <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                    <sort_order>0</sort_order>
                    <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                    <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                    <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                    <fields>
                        <breadcrumbs translate="label">
                            <label>Use Breadcrumbs</label>
                            <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
                            <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_yesno</source_model>
                            <sort_order>10</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                        </breadcrumbs>
                        <url_prefix translate="label comment">
                            <label>URL prefix</label>
                            <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                            <sort_order>20</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                            <comment>Leave empty for no prefix</comment>
                        </url_prefix>
                        <url_suffix translate="label comment">
                            <label>Url suffix</label>
                            <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                            <sort_order>30</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                            <comment>What goes after the dot. Leave empty for no suffix.</comment>
                        </url_suffix>
                        <rss translate="label">
                            <label>Enable rss</label>
                            <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
                            <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_yesno</source_model>
                            <sort_order>40</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                        </rss>
                        <meta_title translate="label">
                            <label>Meta title for articles list page</label>
                            <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                            <sort_order>50</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                        </meta_title>
                        <meta_description translate="label">
                            <label>Meta description for articles list page</label>
                            <frontend_type>textarea</frontend_type>
                            <sort_order>60</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                        </meta_description>
                        <meta_keywords translate="label">
                            <label>Meta keywords for articles list page</label>
                            <frontend_type>textarea</frontend_type>
                            <sort_order>70</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                        </meta_keywords>
                    </fields>
                </article>
            </groups>
        </easylife_news>
    </sections>
</config>
```

`app/code/local/Easylife/News/sql/easylife_news_setup/install-1.0.0.php` - the install script

```
<?php
$this->startSetup();
//create the entity table
$table = $this->getConnection()
    ->newTable($this->getTable('easylife_news/article'))
    ->addColumn('entity_id', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_INTEGER, null, array(
        'identity'  => true,
        'unsigned'  => true,
        'nullable'  => false,
        'primary'   => true,
        ), 'Entity ID')
    ->addColumn('entity_type_id', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_SMALLINT, null, array(
        'unsigned'  => true,
        'nullable'  => false,
        'default'   => '0',
        ), 'Entity Type ID')
    ->addColumn('attribute_set_id', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_SMALLINT, null, array(
        'unsigned'  => true,
        'nullable'  => false,
        'default'   => '0',
        ), 'Attribute Set ID')
    ->addColumn('created_at', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_TIMESTAMP, null, array(
        ), 'Creation Time')
    ->addColumn('updated_at', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_TIMESTAMP, null, array(
        ), 'Update Time')
    ->addIndex($this->getIdxName('easylife_news/article', array('entity_type_id')),
        array('entity_type_id'))
    ->addIndex($this->getIdxName('easylife_news/article', array('attribute_set_id')),
        array('attribute_set_id'))
    ->addForeignKey(
        $this->getFkName(
            'easylife_news/article',
            'attribute_set_id',
            'eav/attribute_set',
            'attribute_set_id'
        ),
        'attribute_set_id', $this->getTable('eav/attribute_set'), 'attribute_set_id',
        Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::ACTION_CASCADE, Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::ACTION_CASCADE)
    ->addForeignKey($this->getFkName('easylife_news/article', 'entity_type_id', 'eav/entity_type', 'entity_type_id'),
        'entity_type_id', $this->getTable('eav/entity_type'), 'entity_type_id',
        Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::ACTION_CASCADE, Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::ACTION_CASCADE)
    ->setComment('Article Table');
$this->getConnection()->createTable($table);

//create the attribute values tables (int, decimal, varchar, text, datetime)
$articleEav = array();
$articleEav['int'] = array(
    'type'      => Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_INTEGER,
    'length'    => null,
    'comment'   => 'Article Datetime Attribute Backend Table'
);

$articleEav['varchar'] = array(
    'type'      => Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_TEXT,
    'length'    => 255,
    'comment'   => 'Article Varchar Attribute Backend Table'
);

$articleEav['text'] = array(
    'type'      => Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_TEXT,
    'length'    => '64k',
    'comment'   => 'Article Text Attribute Backend Table'
);

$articleEav['datetime'] = array(
    'type'      => Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_DATETIME,
    'length'    => null,
    'comment'   => 'Article Datetime Attribute Backend Table'
);

$articleEav['decimal'] = array(
    'type'      => Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_DECIMAL,
    'length'    => '12,4',
    'comment'   => 'Article Datetime Attribute Backend Table'
);

foreach ($articleEav as $type => $options) {
    $table = $this->getConnection()
        ->newTable($this->getTable(array('easylife_news/article', $type)))
        ->addColumn('value_id', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_INTEGER, null, array(
            'identity'  => true,
            'nullable'  => false,
            'primary'   => true,
            ), 'Value ID')
        ->addColumn('entity_type_id', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_SMALLINT, null, array(
            'unsigned'  => true,
            'nullable'  => false,
            'default'   => '0',
            ), 'Entity Type ID')
        ->addColumn('attribute_id', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_SMALLINT, null, array(
            'unsigned'  => true,
            'nullable'  => false,
            'default'   => '0',
            ), 'Attribute ID')
        ->addColumn('store_id', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_SMALLINT, null, array(
            'unsigned'  => true,
            'nullable'  => false,
            'default'   => '0',
            ), 'Store ID')
        ->addColumn('entity_id', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_INTEGER, null, array(
            'unsigned'  => true,
            'nullable'  => false,
            'default'   => '0',
            ), 'Entity ID')
        ->addColumn('value', $options['type'], $options['length'], array(
            ), 'Value')
        ->addIndex(
            $this->getIdxName(
                array('easylife_news/article', $type),
                array('entity_id', 'attribute_id', 'store_id'),
                Varien_Db_Adapter_Interface::INDEX_TYPE_UNIQUE
            ),
            array('entity_id', 'attribute_id', 'store_id'),
            array('type' => Varien_Db_Adapter_Interface::INDEX_TYPE_UNIQUE))
        ->addIndex($this->getIdxName(array('easylife_news/article', $type), array('store_id')),
            array('store_id'))
        ->addIndex($this->getIdxName(array('easylife_news/article', $type), array('entity_id')),
            array('entity_id'))
        ->addIndex($this->getIdxName(array('easylife_news/article', $type), array('attribute_id')),
            array('attribute_id'))
        ->addForeignKey(
            $this->getFkName(
                array('easylife_news/article', $type),
                'attribute_id',
                'eav/attribute',
                'attribute_id'
            ),
            'attribute_id', $this->getTable('eav/attribute'), 'attribute_id',
            Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::ACTION_CASCADE, Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::ACTION_CASCADE)
        ->addForeignKey(
            $this->getFkName(
                array('easylife_news/article', $type),
                'entity_id',
                'easylife_news/article',
                'entity_id'
            ),
            'entity_id', $this->getTable('easylife_news/article'), 'entity_id',
            Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::ACTION_CASCADE, Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::ACTION_CASCADE)
        ->addForeignKey($this->getFkName(array('easylife_news/article', $type), 'store_id', 'core/store', 'store_id'),
            'store_id', $this->getTable('core/store'), 'store_id',
            Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::ACTION_CASCADE, Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::ACTION_CASCADE)
        ->setComment($options['comment']);
    $this->getConnection()->createTable($table);
}
//crete the news_eav_attribute (for additional attribute settings)
$table = $this->getConnection()
    ->newTable($this->getTable('easylife_news/eav_attribute'))
    ->addColumn('attribute_id', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_INTEGER, null, array(
        'identity'  => true,
        'nullable'  => false,
        'primary'   => true,
        ), 'Attribute ID')
    ->addColumn('is_global', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_INTEGER, null, array(), 'Attribute scope')
    ->addColumn('position', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_INTEGER, null, array(), 'Attribute position')
    ->addColumn('is_wysiwyg_enabled', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_INTEGER, null, array(), 'Attribute uses WYSIWYG')
    ->addColumn('is_visible', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_INTEGER, null, array(), 'Attribute is visible')
    ->setComment('News attribute table');
$this->getConnection()->createTable($table);

$this->installEntities();
$this->endSetup();
```

**Models**
`app/code/local/Easylife/News/Model/Observer.php` - add the new menu item on the top menu:

```
<?php
class Easylife_News_Model_Observer {
    public function addItemsToTopmenuItems($observer) {
        $menu = $observer->getMenu();
        $tree = $menu->getTree();
        $action = Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getAction()->getFullActionName();

        $articleNodeId = 'article';
        $data = array(
            'name' => Mage::helper('easylife_news')->__('Articles'),
            'id' => $articleNodeId,
            'url' => Mage::helper('easylife_news/article')->getArticlesUrl(),
            'is_active' => ($action == 'easylife_news_article_index' || $action == 'easylife_news_article_view')
        );
        $articleNode = new Varien_Data_Tree_Node($data, 'id', $tree, $menu);
        $menu->addChild($articleNode);
        return $this;
    }
}
```

`app/code/local/Easylife/News/Model/Article.php` - the article main model

```
<?php
class Easylife_News_Model_Article
    extends Mage_Catalog_Model_Abstract {
    const ENTITY    = 'easylife_news_article';
    const CACHE_TAG = 'easylife_news_article';
    protected $_eventPrefix = 'easylife_news_article';
    protected $_eventObject = 'article';
    public function _construct(){
        parent::_construct();
        $this->_init('easylife_news/article');
    }
    protected function _beforeSave(){
        parent::_beforeSave();
        $now = Mage::getSingleton('core/date')->gmtDate();
        if ($this->isObjectNew()){
            $this->setCreatedAt($now);
        }
        $this->setUpdatedAt($now);
        return $this;
    }
    public function getArticleUrl(){
        if ($this->getUrlKey()){
            $urlKey = '';
            if ($prefix = Mage::getStoreConfig('easylife_news/article/url_prefix')){
                $urlKey .= $prefix.'/';
            }
            $urlKey .= $this->getUrlKey();
            if ($suffix = Mage::getStoreConfig('easylife_news/article/url_suffix')){
                $urlKey .= '.'.$suffix;
            }
            return Mage::getUrl('', array('_direct'=>$urlKey));
        }
        return Mage::getUrl('easylife_news/article/view', array('id'=>$this->getId()));
    }
    public function checkUrlKey($urlKey, $active = true){
        return $this->_getResource()->checkUrlKey($urlKey, $active);
    }

    public function getDescription(){ //this needs to be implemented for all WYSIWYG attributes
        $description = $this->getData('description');
        $helper = Mage::helper('cms');
        $processor = $helper->getBlockTemplateProcessor();
        $html = $processor->filter($description);
        return $html;
    }
    public function getDefaultAttributeSetId() {
        return $this->getResource()->getEntityType()->getDefaultAttributeSetId();
    }
    public function getAttributeText($attributeCode) {
        $text = $this->getResource()
            ->getAttribute($attributeCode)
            ->getSource()
            ->getOptionText($this->getData($attributeCode));
        if (is_array($text)){
            return implode(', ',$text);
        }
        return $text;
    }
    public function getDefaultValues() {
        $values = array();
        $values['status'] = 1;
        $values['in_rss'] = 1;
        return $values;
    }
}
```

`app/code/local/Easylife/News/Model/Resource/Article.php` - the resource model for the article

```
<?php
class Easylife_News_Model_Resource_Article
    extends Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Abstract {
    public function __construct() {
        $resource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
        $this->setType('easylife_news_article')
            ->setConnection(
                $resource->getConnection('article_read'),
                $resource->getConnection('article_write')
            );

    }
    public function getMainTable() {
        return $this->getEntityTable();
    }
    public function checkUrlKey($urlKey, $storeId, $active = true){
        $stores = array(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID, $storeId);
        $select = $this->_initCheckUrlKeySelect($urlKey, $stores);
        if (!$select){
            return false;
        }
        $select->reset(Zend_Db_Select::COLUMNS)
            ->columns('e.entity_id')
            ->limit(1);
        return $this->_getReadAdapter()->fetchOne($select);
    }
    protected function _initCheckUrlKeySelect($urlKey, $store){
        $urlRewrite = Mage::getModel('eav/config')->getAttribute('easylife_news_article', 'url_key');
        if (!$urlRewrite || !$urlRewrite->getId()){
            return false;
        }
        $table = $urlRewrite->getBackend()->getTable();
        $select = $this->_getReadAdapter()->select()
            ->from(array('e' => $table))
            ->where('e.attribute_id = ?', $urlRewrite->getId())
            ->where('e.value = ?', $urlKey)
            ->where('e.store_id IN (?)', $store)
            ->order('e.store_id DESC');
        return $select;
    }
}
```

`app/code/local/Easylife/News/Model/Resource/Article/Collection.php` - the collection model

```
<?php
class Easylife_News_Model_Resource_Article_Collection
    extends Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Collection_Abstract {
    protected function _construct(){
        parent::_construct();
        $this->_init('easylife_news/article');
    }
    protected function _toOptionArray($valueField='entity_id', $labelField='title', $additional=array()){
        $this->addAttributeToSelect('title');
        return parent::_toOptionArray($valueField, $labelField, $additional);
    }
    protected function _toOptionHash($valueField='entity_id', $labelField='title'){
        $this->addAttributeToSelect('title');
        return parent::_toOptionHash($valueField, $labelField);
    }
    public function getSelectCountSql(){
        $countSelect = parent::getSelectCountSql();
        $countSelect->reset(Zend_Db_Select::GROUP);
        return $countSelect;
    }
}
```

The code is too long to fit in one answer. The rest will follow....wait for it.

Comment: Marius : Seems to Great job

Comment: Can you elaborate which part of code used for store swicher

Comment: @AmitKamboj. Wait for it...I'm getting there. I'm not done with the answers

Comment: @AmitKamboj. Look at part 6. in the layout admin file there is a reference to the store switcher. You can start from there

Answer (score 12):

**Part 2**.

`app/code/local/Easylife/News/Model/Attribute.php` - the model for the article attributes

```
<?php
class Easylife_News_Model_Attribute
    extends Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute {
    const SCOPE_STORE                           = 0;
    const SCOPE_GLOBAL                          = 1;
    const SCOPE_WEBSITE                         = 2;
    const MODULE_NAME                           = 'Easylife_News';
    const ENTITY                                = 'easylife_news_eav_attribute';
    protected $_eventPrefix                     = 'easylife_news_entity_attribute';
    protected $_eventObject                     = 'attribute';
    static protected $_labels                   = null;
    protected function _construct(){
        $this->_init('easylife_news/attribute');
    }
    protected function _beforeSave(){
        $this->setData('modulePrefix', self::MODULE_NAME);
        if (isset($this->_origData['is_global'])) {
            if (!isset($this->_data['is_global'])) {
                $this->_data['is_global'] = self::SCOPE_GLOBAL;
            }
        }
        if ($this->getFrontendInput() == 'textarea') {
            if ($this->getIsWysiwygEnabled()) {
                $this->setIsHtmlAllowedOnFront(1);
            }
        }
        return parent::_beforeSave();
    }
    protected function _afterSave(){
        Mage::getSingleton('eav/config')->clear();
        return parent::_afterSave();
    }
    public function getIsGlobal(){
        return $this->_getData('is_global');
    }
    public function isScopeGlobal(){
        return $this->getIsGlobal() == self::SCOPE_GLOBAL;
    }
    public function isScopeWebsite(){
        return $this->getIsGlobal() == self::SCOPE_WEBSITE;
    }
    public function isScopeStore(){
        return !$this->isScopeGlobal() && !$this->isScopeWebsite();
    }
    public function getStoreId(){
        $dataObject = $this->getDataObject();
        if ($dataObject) {
            return $dataObject->getStoreId();
        }
        return $this->getData('store_id');
    }
    public function getSourceModel(){
        $model = $this->getData('source_model');
        if (empty($model)) {
            if ($this->getBackendType() == 'int' && $this->getFrontendInput() == 'select') {
                return $this->_getDefaultSourceModel();
            }
        }
        return $model;
    }
    public function getFrontendLabel(){
        return $this->_getData('frontend_label');
    }
    protected function _getLabelForStore(){
        return $this->getFrontendLabel();
    }
    public static function initLabels($storeId = null){
        if (is_null(self::$_labels)) {
            if (is_null($storeId)) {
                $storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getId();
            }
            $attributeLabels = array();
            $attributes = Mage::getResourceSingleton('catalog/product')->getAttributesByCode();
            foreach ($attributes as $attribute) {
                if (strlen($attribute->getData('frontend_label')) > 0) {
                    $attributeLabels[] = $attribute->getData('frontend_label');
                }
            }
            self::$_labels = Mage::app()->getTranslator()->getResource()->getTranslationArrayByStrings($attributeLabels, $storeId);
        }
    }
    public function _getDefaultSourceModel(){
        return 'eav/entity_attribute_source_table';
    }
}
```

`app/code/local/Easylife/News/Model/Resource/Attribute.php` - the attribute resource model

```
<?php
class Easylife_News_Model_Resource_Attribute
    extends Mage_Eav_Model_Resource_Entity_Attribute {
    protected  function _afterSave(Mage_Core_Model_Abstract $object){
        $setup       = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_setup', 'core_write');
        $entityType  = $object->getEntityTypeId();
        $setId       = $setup->getDefaultAttributeSetId($entityType);
        $groupId     = $setup->getDefaultAttributeGroupId($entityType);
        $attributeId = $object->getId();
        $sortOrder   = $object->getPosition();

        $setup->addAttributeToGroup($entityType, $setId, $groupId, $attributeId, $sortOrder);
        return parent::_afterSave($object);
    }
}
```

`app/code/local/Easylife/News/Model/Resource/Eav/Attribute.php` - the attribute EAV resource model

```
<?php
class Easylife_News_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute
    extends Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute {
    const MODULE_NAME   = 'Easylife_News';
    const ENTITY        = 'easylife_news_eav_attribute';
    protected $_eventPrefix = 'easylife_news_entity_attribute';
    protected $_eventObject = 'attribute';
    static protected $_labels = null;
    protected function _construct() {
        $this->_init('easylife_news/attribute');
    }
    public function isScopeStore() {
        return $this->getIsGlobal() == Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_STORE;
    }
    public function isScopeWebsite() {
        return $this->getIsGlobal() == Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_WEBSITE;
    }
    public function isScopeGlobal() {
        return (!$this->isScopeStore() && !$this->isScopeWebsite());
    }
    public function getBackendTypeByInput($type) {
        switch ($type){
            case 'file':
                //intentional fallthrough
            case 'image':
                return 'varchar';
                break;
            default:
                return parent::getBackendTypeByInput($type);
            break;
        }
    }
    protected function _beforeDelete(){
        if (!$this->getIsUserDefined()){
            throw new Mage_Core_Exception(Mage::helper('easylife_news')->__('This attribute is not deletable'));
        }
        return parent::_beforeDelete();
    }
}
```

`app/code/local/Easylife/News/Model/Resource/Article/Collection.php` - attribute collection model

```
<?php
class Easylife_News_Model_Resource_Article_Attribute_Collection
    extends Mage_Eav_Model_Resource_Entity_Attribute_Collection {
    protected function _initSelect() {
            $this->getSelect()->from(array('main_table' => $this->getResource()->getMainTable()))
                ->where('main_table.entity_type_id=?', Mage::getModel('eav/entity')->setType('easylife_news_article')->getTypeId())
                ->join(
                    array('additional_table' => $this->getTable('easylife_news/eav_attribute')),
                    'additional_table.attribute_id=main_table.attribute_id'
                );
        return $this;
    }
    public function setEntityTypeFilter($typeId) {
        return $this;
    }
    public function addVisibleFilter() {
        return $this->addFieldToFilter('additional_table.is_visible', 1);
    }
    public function addEditableFilter() {
        return $this->addFieldToFilter('additional_table.is_editable', 1);
    }
}
```

`app/code/local/Easylife/News/Model/Resource/Setup.php` - the setup resource model - used for adding the entities and attribtues:

```
<?php
class Easylife_News_Model_Resource_Setup
    extends Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Setup {
    public function getDefaultEntities(){
    $entities = array();
        $entities['easylife_news_article'] = array(
            'entity_model'                  => 'easylife_news/article',
            'attribute_model'               => 'easylife_news/resource_eav_attribute',
            'table'                         => 'easylife_news/article',
            'additional_attribute_table'    => 'easylife_news/eav_attribute',
            'entity_attribute_collection'   => 'easylife_news/article_attribute_collection',
            'attributes'        => array(
                    'title' => array(
                        'group'          => 'General',
                        'type'           => 'varchar',
                        'backend'        => '',
                        'frontend'       => '',
                        'label'          => 'Title',
                        'input'          => 'text',
                        'source'         => '',
                        'global'         => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_STORE,
                        'required'       => '1',
                        'user_defined'   => false,
                        'default'        => '',
                        'unique'         => false,
                        'position'       => '10',
                        'note'           => '',
                        'visible'        => '1',
                        'wysiwyg_enabled'=> '0',
                    ),
                    'short_description' => array(
                        'group'          => 'General',
                        'type'           => 'text',
                        'backend'        => '',
                        'frontend'       => '',
                        'label'          => 'Short description',
                        'input'          => 'textarea',
                        'source'         => '',
                        'global'         => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_STORE,
                        'required'       => '1',
                        'user_defined'   => true,
                        'default'        => '',
                        'unique'         => false,
                        'position'       => '20',
                        'note'           => '',
                        'visible'        => '1',
                        'wysiwyg_enabled'=> '0',
                    ),
                    'description' => array(
                        'group'          => 'General',
                        'type'           => 'text',
                        'backend'        => '',
                        'frontend'       => '',
                        'label'          => 'Description',
                        'input'          => 'textarea',
                        'source'         => '',
                        'global'         => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_STORE,
                        'required'       => '1',
                        'user_defined'   => true,
                        'default'        => '',
                        'unique'         => false,
                        'position'       => '30',
                        'note'           => '',
                        'visible'        => '1',
                        'wysiwyg_enabled'=> '1',
                    ),
                    'publish_date' => array(
                        'group'          => 'General',
                        'type'           => 'datetime',
                        'backend'        => 'eav/entity_attribute_backend_datetime',
                        'frontend'       => '',
                        'label'          => 'Publish Date',
                        'input'          => 'date',
                        'source'         => '',
                        'global'         => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
                        'required'       => '1',
                        'user_defined'   => true,
                        'default'        => '',
                        'unique'         => false,
                        'position'       => '40',
                        'note'           => '',
                        'visible'        => '1',
                        'wysiwyg_enabled'=> '0',
                    ),
                    'status' => array(
                        'group'          => 'General',
                        'type'           => 'int',
                        'backend'        => '',
                        'frontend'       => '',
                        'label'          => 'Enabled',
                        'input'          => 'select',
                        'source'         => 'eav/entity_attribute_source_boolean',
                        'global'         => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_STORE,
                        'required'       => '',
                        'user_defined'   => false,
                        'default'        => '',
                        'unique'         => false,
                        'position'       => '50',
                        'note'           => '',
                        'visible'        => '1',
                        'wysiwyg_enabled'=> '0',
                    ),
                    'url_key' => array(
                        'group'          => 'General',
                        'type'           => 'varchar',
                        'backend'        => 'easylife_news/article_attribute_backend_urlkey',
                        'frontend'       => '',
                        'label'          => 'URL key',
                        'input'          => 'text',
                        'source'         => '',
                        'global'         => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_STORE,
                        'required'       => '',
                        'user_defined'   => false,
                        'default'        => '',
                        'unique'         => false,
                        'position'       => '60',
                        'note'           => '',
                        'visible'        => '1',
                        'wysiwyg_enabled'=> '0',
                    ),
                    'in_rss' => array(
                        'group'          => 'General',
                        'type'           => 'int',
                        'backend'        => '',
                        'frontend'       => '',
                        'label'          => 'In RSS',
                        'input'          => 'select',
                        'source'         => 'eav/entity_attribute_source_boolean',
                        'global'         => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_STORE,
                        'required'       => '',
                        'user_defined'   => false,
                        'default'        => '',
                        'unique'         => false,
                        'position'       => '70',
                        'note'           => '',
                        'visible'        => '1',
                        'wysiwyg_enabled'=> '0',
                    ),
                    'meta_title' => array(
                        'group'          => 'General',
                        'type'           => 'varchar',
                        'backend'        => '',
                        'frontend'       => '',
                        'label'          => 'Meta title',
                        'input'          => 'text',
                        'source'         => '',
                        'global'         => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_STORE,
                        'required'       => '',
                        'user_defined'   => false,
                        'default'        => '',
                        'unique'         => false,
                        'position'       => '80',
                        'note'           => '',
                        'visible'        => '1',
                        'wysiwyg_enabled'=> '0',
                    ),
                    'meta_keywords' => array(
                        'group'          => 'General',
                        'type'           => 'text',
                        'backend'        => '',
                        'frontend'       => '',
                        'label'          => 'Meta keywords',
                        'input'          => 'textarea',
                        'source'         => '',
                        'global'         => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_STORE,
                        'required'       => '',
                        'user_defined'   => false,
                        'default'        => '',
                        'unique'         => false,
                        'position'       => '90',
                        'note'           => '',
                        'visible'        => '1',
                        'wysiwyg_enabled'=> '0',
                    ),
                    'meta_description' => array(
                        'group'          => 'General',
                        'type'           => 'text',
                        'backend'        => '',
                        'frontend'       => '',
                        'label'          => 'Meta description',
                        'input'          => 'textarea',
                        'source'         => '',
                        'global'         => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_STORE,
                        'required'       => '',
                        'user_defined'   => false,
                        'default'        => '',
                        'unique'         => false,
                        'position'       => '100',
                        'note'           => '',
                        'visible'        => '1',
                        'wysiwyg_enabled'=> '0',
                    ),

                )
        );
        return $entities;
    }
}
```

`app/code/local/Easylife/News/Model/Article/Attribute/Backend/File.php` - backend for file attributes if you decide to add one

```
<?php
class Easylife_News_Model_Article_Attribute_Backend_File
    extends Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute_Backend_Abstract {
    public function afterSave($object){
        $value = $object->getData($this->getAttribute()->getName());

        if (is_array($value) && !empty($value['delete'])) {
            $object->setData($this->getAttribute()->getName(), '');
            $this->getAttribute()->getEntity()
                ->saveAttribute($object, $this->getAttribute()->getName());
            return;
        }

        $path = Mage::helper('easylife_news/article')->getFileBaseDir();

        try {
            $uploader = new Varien_File_Uploader($this->getAttribute()->getName());
            //set allowed file extensions if you need
            //$uploader->setAllowedExtensions(array('mp4', 'mov', 'f4v', 'flv', '3gp', '3g2', 'mp3', 'aac', 'm4a', 'swf'));
            $uploader->setAllowRenameFiles(true);
            $uploader->setFilesDispersion(true);
            $result = $uploader->save($path);
            $object->setData($this->getAttribute()->getName(), $result['file']);
            $this->getAttribute()->getEntity()->saveAttribute($object, $this->getAttribute()->getName());
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            if ($e->getCode() != 666){
                //throw $e;
            }
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

`app/code/local/Easylife/News/Model/Article/Attribute/Backend/Image.php` - backend for image attributes if you decide to add one

```
<?php
class Easylife_News_Model_Article_Attribute_Backend_Image
    extends Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute_Backend_Abstract {
    public function afterSave($object){
        $value = $object->getData($this->getAttribute()->getName());

        if (is_array($value) && !empty($value['delete'])) {
            $object->setData($this->getAttribute()->getName(), '');
            $this->getAttribute()->getEntity()
                ->saveAttribute($object, $this->getAttribute()->getName());
            return;
        }

        $path = Mage::helper('easylife_news/article_image')->getImageBaseDir();

        try {
            $uploader = new Varien_File_Uploader($this->getAttribute()->getName());
            $uploader->setAllowRenameFiles(true);
            $uploader->setFilesDispersion(true);
            $result = $uploader->save($path);
            $object->setData($this->getAttribute()->getName(), $result['file']);
            $this->getAttribute()->getEntity()->saveAttribute($object, $this->getAttribute()->getName());
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            if ($e->getCode() != 666){
                //throw $e;
            }
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

`app/code/local/Easylife/News/Model/Article/Attribute/Backend/Urlkey.php` - backend for url key attribute

```
<?php
class Easylife_News_Model_Article_Attribute_Backend_Urlkey
    extends Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute_Backend_Abstract {
    public function beforeSave($object) {
        $attributeName = $this->getAttribute()->getName();
        $urlKey = $object->getData($attributeName);
        if ($urlKey == '') {
            $urlKey = $object->getTitle();
        }
        $urlKey = $this->formatUrlKey($urlKey);
        $validKey = false;
        while (!$validKey) {
            $entityId = Mage::getResourceModel('easylife_news/article')->checkUrlKey($urlKey, $object->getStoreId(), false);
            if ($entityId == $object->getId() || empty($entityId)) {
                $validKey = true;
            }
            else {
                $parts = explode('-', $urlKey);
                $last = $parts[count($parts) - 1];
                if (!is_numeric($last)){
                    $urlKey = $urlKey.'-1';
                }
                else {
                    $suffix = '-'.($last + 1);
                    unset($parts[count($parts) - 1]);
                    $urlKey = implode('-', $parts).$suffix;
                }
            }
        }
        $object->setData($attributeName, $urlKey);
        return $this;
    }
    public function formatUrlKey($str) {
        $urlKey = preg_replace('#[^0-9a-z]+#i', '-', Mage::helper('catalog/product_url')->format($str));
        $urlKey = strtolower($urlKey);
        $urlKey = trim($urlKey, '-');
        return $urlKey;
    }
}
```

`app/code/local/Easylife/News/Model/Adminhtml/Search/Article.php` - model that handles the admin global search

```
<?php
class Easylife_News_Model_Adminhtml_Search_Article
    extends Varien_Object {
    public function load(){
        $arr = array();
        if (!$this->hasStart() || !$this->hasLimit() || !$this->hasQuery()) {
            $this->setResults($arr);
            return $this;
        }
        $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('easylife_news/article_collection')
            ->addAttributeToFilter('title', array('like' => $this->getQuery().'%'))
            ->setCurPage($this->getStart())
            ->setPageSize($this->getLimit())
            ->load();
        foreach ($collection->getItems() as $article) {
            $arr[] = array(
                'id'=> 'article/1/'.$article->getId(),
                'type'  => Mage::helper('easylife_news')->__('Article'),
                'name'  => $article->getTitle(),
                'description'   => $article->getTitle(),
                'url' => Mage::helper('adminhtml')->getUrl('*/news_article/edit', array('id'=>$article->getId())),
            );
        }
        $this->setResults($arr);
        return $this;
    }
}
```

We're done with the models. Let's go on to **blocks**.
`app/code/local/Easylife/News/Block/Rss.php` - the general rss block

```
<?php 
class Easylife_News_Block_Rss
    extends Mage_Core_Block_Template {
    protected $_feeds = array();
    public function addFeed($label, $url, $prepare = false) {
        $link = ($prepare ? $this->getUrl($url) : $url);
        $feed = new Varien_Object();
        $feed->setLabel($label);
        $feed->setUrl($link);
        $this->_feeds[$link] = $feed;
        return $this;
    }
    public function getFeeds() {
        return $this->_feeds;
    }
}
```

`app/code/local/Easylife/News/Block/Adminhtml/Article.php` - the main article block

```
<?php
class Easylife_News_Block_Adminhtml_Article
    extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Container {
    public function __construct(){
        $this->_controller         = 'adminhtml_article';
        $this->_blockGroup         = 'easylife_news';
        parent::__construct();
        $this->_headerText         = Mage::helper('easylife_news')->__('Article');
        $this->_updateButton('add', 'label', Mage::helper('easylife_news')->__('Add Article'));

        $this->setTemplate('easylife_news/grid.phtml');
    }
}
```

`app/code/local/Easylife/News/Block/Adminhtml/Article/Edit.php` - the admin edit form

```
<?php
class Easylife_News_Block_Adminhtml_Article_Edit
    extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form_Container {
    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        $this->_blockGroup = 'easylife_news';
        $this->_controller = 'adminhtml_article';
        $this->_updateButton('save', 'label', Mage::helper('easylife_news')->__('Save Article'));
        $this->_updateButton('delete', 'label', Mage::helper('easylife_news')->__('Delete Article'));
        $this->_addButton('saveandcontinue', array(
            'label'        => Mage::helper('easylife_news')->__('Save And Continue Edit'),
            'onclick'    => 'saveAndContinueEdit()',
            'class'        => 'save',
        ), -100);
        $this->_formScripts[] = "
            function saveAndContinueEdit(){
                editForm.submit($('edit_form').action+'back/edit/');
            }
        ";
    }
    public function getHeaderText(){
        if( Mage::registry('current_article') && Mage::registry('current_article')->getId() ) {
            return Mage::helper('easylife_news')->__("Edit Article '%s'", $this->escapeHtml(Mage::registry('current_article')->getTitle()));
        }
        else {
            return Mage::helper('easylife_news')->__('Add Article');
        }
    }
}
```

Looks like there will be a part 3.....

Answer (score 10):

**Part 3.**
`app/code/local/Easylife/News/Block/Adminhtml/Article/Grid.php` - the admin grid

```
<?php
class Easylife_News_Block_Adminhtml_Article_Grid
    extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid {
    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        $this->setId('articleGrid');
        $this->setDefaultSort('entity_id');
        $this->setDefaultDir('ASC');
        $this->setSaveParametersInSession(true);
        $this->setUseAjax(true);
    }
    protected function _prepareCollection(){
        $collection = Mage::getModel('easylife_news/article')->getCollection()
            ->addAttributeToSelect('publish_date')
            ->addAttributeToSelect('status')
            ->addAttributeToSelect('url_key');
        $adminStore = Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID;
        $store = $this->_getStore();
        $collection->joinAttribute('title', 'easylife_news_article/title', 'entity_id', null, 'inner', $adminStore);
        if ($store->getId()) {
            $collection->joinAttribute('easylife_news_article_title', 'easylife_news_article/title', 'entity_id', null, 'inner', $store->getId());
        }

        $this->setCollection($collection);
        return parent::_prepareCollection();
    }
    protected function _prepareColumns(){
        $this->addColumn('entity_id', array(
            'header'    => Mage::helper('easylife_news')->__('Id'),
            'index'        => 'entity_id',
            'type'        => 'number'
        ));
        $this->addColumn('title', array(
            'header'    => Mage::helper('easylife_news')->__('Title'),
            'align'     => 'left',
            'index'     => 'title',
        ));
        if ($this->_getStore()->getId()){
            $this->addColumn('easylife_news_article_title', array(
                'header'    => Mage::helper('easylife_news')->__('Title in %s', $this->_getStore()->getName()),
                'align'     => 'left',
                'index'     => 'easylife_news_article_title',
            ));
        }

        $this->addColumn('status', array(
            'header'    => Mage::helper('easylife_news')->__('Status'),
            'index'        => 'status',
            'type'        => 'options',
            'options'    => array(
                '1' => Mage::helper('easylife_news')->__('Enabled'),
                '0' => Mage::helper('easylife_news')->__('Disabled'),
            )
        ));
        $this->addColumn('publish_date', array(
            'header'=> Mage::helper('easylife_news')->__('Publish Date'),
            'index' => 'publish_date',
            'type'=> 'date',

        ));
        $this->addColumn('url_key', array(
            'header' => Mage::helper('easylife_news')->__('URL key'),
            'index'  => 'url_key',
        ));
        $this->addColumn('created_at', array(
            'header'    => Mage::helper('easylife_news')->__('Created at'),
            'index'     => 'created_at',
            'width'     => '120px',
            'type'      => 'datetime',
        ));
        $this->addColumn('updated_at', array(
            'header'    => Mage::helper('easylife_news')->__('Updated at'),
            'index'     => 'updated_at',
            'width'     => '120px',
            'type'      => 'datetime',
        ));
        $this->addColumn('action',
            array(
                'header'=>  Mage::helper('easylife_news')->__('Action'),
                'width' => '100',
                'type'  => 'action',
                'getter'=> 'getId',
                'actions'   => array(
                    array(
                        'caption'   => Mage::helper('easylife_news')->__('Edit'),
                        'url'   => array('base'=> '*/*/edit'),
                        'field' => 'id'
                    )
                ),
                'filter'=> false,
                'is_system'    => true,
                'sortable'  => false,
        ));
        $this->addExportType('*/*/exportCsv', Mage::helper('easylife_news')->__('CSV'));
        $this->addExportType('*/*/exportExcel', Mage::helper('easylife_news')->__('Excel'));
        $this->addExportType('*/*/exportXml', Mage::helper('easylife_news')->__('XML'));
        return parent::_prepareColumns();
    }

    protected function _getStore(){
        $storeId = (int) $this->getRequest()->getParam('store', 0);
        return Mage::app()->getStore($storeId);
    }

    protected function _prepareMassaction(){
        $this->setMassactionIdField('entity_id');
        $this->getMassactionBlock()->setFormFieldName('article');
        $this->getMassactionBlock()->addItem('delete', array(
            'label'=> Mage::helper('easylife_news')->__('Delete'),
            'url'  => $this->getUrl('*/*/massDelete'),
            'confirm'  => Mage::helper('easylife_news')->__('Are you sure?')
        ));
        $this->getMassactionBlock()->addItem('status', array(
            'label'=> Mage::helper('easylife_news')->__('Change status'),
            'url'  => $this->getUrl('*/*/massStatus', array('_current'=>true)),
            'additional' => array(
                'status' => array(
                        'name' => 'status',
                        'type' => 'select',
                        'class' => 'required-entry',
                        'label' => Mage::helper('easylife_news')->__('Status'),
                        'values' => array(
                                '1' => Mage::helper('easylife_news')->__('Enabled'),
                                '0' => Mage::helper('easylife_news')->__('Disabled'),
                        )
                )
            )
        ));
        return $this;
    }

    public function getRowUrl($row){
        return $this->getUrl('*/*/edit', array('id' => $row->getId()));
    }
    public function getGridUrl(){
        return $this->getUrl('*/*/grid', array('_current'=>true));
    }
}
```

`app/code/local/Easylife/News/Block/Adminhtml/Article/Edit/Tabs.php` - the tabs in the add/edit form

```
<?php
class Easylife_News_Block_Adminhtml_Article_Edit_Tabs
    extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Tabs {
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->setId('article_info_tabs');
        $this->setDestElementId('edit_form');
        $this->setTitle(Mage::helper('easylife_news')->__('Article Information'));
    }
    protected function _prepareLayout(){
        $article = $this->getArticle();
        $entity = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_type')->load('easylife_news_article', 'entity_type_code');
        $attributes = Mage::getResourceModel('eav/entity_attribute_collection')
                ->setEntityTypeFilter($entity->getEntityTypeId());
        $attributes->addFieldToFilter('attribute_code', array('nin'=>array('meta_title', 'meta_description', 'meta_keywords')));
        $attributes->getSelect()->order('additional_table.position', 'ASC');

        $this->addTab('info', array(
            'label'     => Mage::helper('easylife_news')->__('Article Information'),
            'content'   => $this->getLayout()->createBlock('easylife_news/adminhtml_article_edit_tab_attributes')
                            ->setAttributes($attributes)
                            ->toHtml(),
        ));
        $seoAttributes = Mage::getResourceModel('eav/entity_attribute_collection')
                ->setEntityTypeFilter($entity->getEntityTypeId())
                ->addFieldToFilter('attribute_code', array('in'=>array('meta_title', 'meta_description', 'meta_keywords')));
        $seoAttributes->getSelect()->order('additional_table.position', 'ASC');

        $this->addTab('meta', array(
            'label'     => Mage::helper('easylife_news')->__('Meta'),
            'title'     => Mage::helper('easylife_news')->__('Meta'),
            'content'   => $this->getLayout()->createBlock('easylife_news/adminhtml_article_edit_tab_attributes')
                            ->setAttributes($seoAttributes)
                            ->toHtml(),
        ));
        return parent::_beforeToHtml();
    }
    public function getArticle(){
        return Mage::registry('current_article');
    }
}
```

`app/code/local/Easylife/News/Block/Adminhtml/Article/Edit/Form.php` - the form container

```
<?php
class Easylife_News_Block_Adminhtml_Article_Edit_Form
    extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form {
    protected function _prepareForm() {
        $form = new Varien_Data_Form(array(
                        'id'         => 'edit_form',
                        'action'     => $this->getUrl('*/*/save', array('id' => $this->getRequest()->getParam('id'), 'store' => $this->getRequest()->getParam('store'))),
                        'method'     => 'post',
                        'enctype'    => 'multipart/form-data'
                    )
        );
        $form->setUseContainer(true);
        $this->setForm($form);
        return parent::_prepareForm();
    }
}
```

`app/code/local/Easylife/News/Block/Adminhtml/Article/Edit/Tab/Attribtues.php` - the attributes contained in a tab.

```
<?php
class Easylife_News_Block_Adminhtml_Article_Edit_Tab_Attributes
    extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form {
    protected function _prepareForm() {
        $form = new Varien_Data_Form();
        $form->setDataObject(Mage::registry('current_article'));
        $fieldset = $form->addFieldset('info',
            array(
                'legend'=>Mage::helper('easylife_news')->__('Article Information'),
                 'class'=>'fieldset-wide',
            )
        );
        $attributes = $this->getAttributes();
        foreach ($attributes as $attribute){
            $attribute->setEntity(Mage::getResourceModel('easylife_news/article'));
        }
        $this->_setFieldset($attributes, $fieldset, array());
        $formValues = Mage::registry('current_article')->getData();
        $form->addValues($formValues);
        $form->setFieldNameSuffix('article');
        $this->setForm($form);
    }
    protected function _prepareLayout() {
        Varien_Data_Form::setElementRenderer(
            $this->getLayout()->createBlock('adminhtml/widget_form_renderer_element')
        );
        Varien_Data_Form::setFieldsetRenderer(
            $this->getLayout()->createBlock('adminhtml/widget_form_renderer_fieldset')
        );
        Varien_Data_Form::setFieldsetElementRenderer(
            $this->getLayout()->createBlock('easylife_news/adminhtml_news_renderer_fieldset_element')
        );
    }
    protected function _getAdditionalElementTypes(){
        return array(
            'file'    => Mage::getConfig()->getBlockClassName('easylife_news/adminhtml_article_helper_file'),
            'image' => Mage::getConfig()->getBlockClassName('easylife_news/adminhtml_article_helper_image'),
            'textarea' => Mage::getConfig()->getBlockClassName('adminhtml/catalog_helper_form_wysiwyg')
        );
    }
    public function getArticle() {
        return Mage::registry('current_article');
    }
}
```

`app/code/local/Easylfe/News/Block/Adminhtml/Article/Helper/File.php` - block helper for rendering file elements.

```
<?php
class Easylife_News_Block_Adminhtml_Article_Helper_File
    extends Varien_Data_Form_Element_Abstract {
    public function __construct($data){
        parent::__construct($data);
        $this->setType('file');
    }
    public function getElementHtml(){
        $html = '';
        $this->addClass('input-file');
        $html.= parent::getElementHtml();
        if ($this->getValue()) {
            $url = $this->_getUrl();
            if( !preg_match("/^http\:\/\/|https\:\/\//", $url) ) {
                $url = Mage::helper('easylife_news/article')->getFileBaseUrl() . $url;
            }
            $html .= '<br /><a href="'.$url.'">'.$this->_getUrl().'</a> ';
        }
        $html.= $this->_getDeleteCheckbox();
        return $html;
    }
    protected function _getDeleteCheckbox(){
        $html = '';
        if ($this->getValue()) {
            $label = Mage::helper('easylife_news')->__('Delete File');
            $html .= '<span class="delete-image">';
            $html .= '<input type="checkbox" name="'.parent::getName().'[delete]" value="1" class="checkbox" id="'.$this->getHtmlId().'_delete"'.($this->getDisabled() ? ' disabled="disabled"': '').'/>';
            $html .= '<label for="'.$this->getHtmlId().'_delete"'.($this->getDisabled() ? ' class="disabled"' : '').'> '.$label.'</label>';
            $html .= $this->_getHiddenInput();
            $html .= '</span>';
        }
        return $html;
    }
    protected function _getHiddenInput(){
        return '<input type="hidden" name="'.parent::getName().'[value]" value="'.$this->getValue().'" />';
    }
    protected function _getUrl(){
        return $this->getValue();
    }
    public function getName(){
        return $this->getData('name');
    }
}
```

`app/code/local/Easylfe/News/Block/Adminhtml/Article/Helper/Image.php` - block helper for rendering image elements.

```
<?php
class Easylife_News_Block_Adminhtml_Article_Helper_Image
    extends Varien_Data_Form_Element_Image {
    protected function _getUrl(){
        $url = false;
        if ($this->getValue()) {
            $url = Mage::helper('easylife_news/article_image')->getImageBaseUrl().$this->getValue();
        }
        return $url;
    }
}
```

`app/code/local/Easylife/News/Block/Adminhtml/Attribute.php` - main block for managing attributes

```
<?php
class Easylife_News_Block_Adminhtml_Article_Attribute
    extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Container {
    public function __construct(){
        $this->_controller = 'adminhtml_article_attribute';
        $this->_blockGroup = 'easylife_news';
        $this->_headerText = Mage::helper('easylife_news')->__('Manage Article Attributes');
        parent::__construct();
        $this->_updateButton('add', 'label', Mage::helper('easylife_news')->__('Add New Article Attribute'));
    }
}
```

`app/code/local/Easylife/News/Block/Adminhtml/Attribute/Grid.php` - the attribute grid block

```
<?php
class Easylife_News_Block_Adminhtml_Article_Attribute_Grid
    extends Mage_Eav_Block_Adminhtml_Attribute_Grid_Abstract {
    protected function _prepareCollection(){
        $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('easylife_news/article_attribute_collection')
            ->addVisibleFilter();
        $this->setCollection($collection);
        return parent::_prepareCollection();
    }
    protected function _prepareColumns() {
        parent::_prepareColumns();
        $this->addColumnAfter('is_global', array(
            'header'=>Mage::helper('easylife_news')->__('Scope'),
            'sortable'=>true,
            'index'=>'is_global',
            'type' => 'options',
            'options' => array(
                Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_STORE   =>Mage::helper('easylife_news')->__('Store View'),
                Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_WEBSITE =>Mage::helper('easylife_news')->__('Website'),
                Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_GLOBAL  =>Mage::helper('easylife_news')->__('Global'),
            ),
            'align' => 'center',
        ), 'is_user_defined');
        return $this;
    }
}
```

`app/code/local/Easylife/News/Block/Adminhtml/Attribute/Edit.php` - the attribute edit form.

```
<?php
class Easylife_News_Block_Adminhtml_Article_Attribute_Edit
    extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form_Container {
    public function __construct() {
        $this->_objectId = 'attribute_id';
        $this->_controller = 'adminhtml_article_attribute';
        $this->_blockGroup = 'easylife_news';

        parent::__construct();
        $this->_addButton(
            'save_and_edit_button',
            array(
                'label'     => Mage::helper('easylife_news')->__('Save and Continue Edit'),
                'onclick'   => 'saveAndContinueEdit()',
                'class'     => 'save'
            ),
            100
        );
        $this->_updateButton('save', 'label', Mage::helper('easylife_news')->__('Save Article Attribute'));
        $this->_updateButton('save', 'onclick', 'saveAttribute()');

        if (!Mage::registry('entity_attribute')->getIsUserDefined()) {
            $this->_removeButton('delete');
        } else {
            $this->_updateButton('delete', 'label', Mage::helper('easylife_news')->__('Delete Article Attribute'));
        }
    }
    public function getHeaderText(){
        if (Mage::registry('entity_attribute')->getId()) {
            $frontendLabel = Mage::registry('entity_attribute')->getFrontendLabel();
            if (is_array($frontendLabel)) {
                $frontendLabel = $frontendLabel[0];
            }
            return Mage::helper('easylife_news')->__('Edit Article Attribute "%s"', $this->htmlEscape($frontendLabel));
        }
        else {
            return Mage::helper('easylife_news')->__('New Article Attribute');
        }
    }
    public function getValidationUrl(){
        return $this->getUrl('*/*/validate', array('_current'=>true));
    }
    public function getSaveUrl(){
        return $this->getUrl('*/'.$this->_controller.'/save', array('_current'=>true, 'back'=>null));
    }
}
```

`app/code/local/Easylife/News/Block/Adminhtml/Attribute/Edit/Tabs.php` - the attribute edit tabs

```
<?php
class Easylife_News_Block_Adminhtml_Article_Attribute_Edit_Tabs
    extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Tabs {
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->setId('article_attribute_tabs');
        $this->setDestElementId('edit_form');
        $this->setTitle(Mage::helper('easylife_news')->__('Attribute Information'));
    }
    protected function _beforeToHtml() {
        $this->addTab('main', array(
            'label'     => Mage::helper('easylife_news')->__('Properties'),
            'title'     => Mage::helper('easylife_news')->__('Properties'),
            'content'   => $this->getLayout()->createBlock('easylife_news/adminhtml_article_attribute_edit_tab_main')->toHtml(),
            'active'    => true
        ));
        $this->addTab('labels', array(
            'label'     => Mage::helper('easylife_news')->__('Manage Label / Options'),
            'title'     => Mage::helper('easylife_news')->__('Manage Label / Options'),
            'content'   => $this->getLayout()->createBlock('easylife_news/adminhtml_article_attribute_edit_tab_options')->toHtml(),
        ));
        return parent::_beforeToHtml();
    }
}
```

`app/code/local/Easylife/News/Block/Adminhtml/Attribute/Edit/Form.php` - the attribute edit form container

```
<?php
class Easylife_News_Block_Adminhtml_Article_Attribute_Edit_Form
    extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form {
    protected function _prepareForm() {
        $form = new Varien_Data_Form(array('id' => 'edit_form', 'action' => $this->getUrl('adminhtml/news_article_attribute/save'), 'method' => 'post'));
        $form->setUseContainer(true);
        $this->setForm($form);
        return parent::_prepareForm();
    }
}
```

`app/code/local/Easylife/News/Block/Adminhtml/Attribute/Edit/Tab/Main.php` - the attribute edit main tab:

```
<?php
class Easylife_News_Block_Adminhtml_Article_Attribute_Edit_Tab_Main
    extends Mage_Eav_Block_Adminhtml_Attribute_Edit_Main_Abstract {
    protected function _prepareForm(){
        parent::_prepareForm();
        $attributeObject = $this->getAttributeObject();
        $form = $this->getForm();
        $fieldset = $form->getElement('base_fieldset');
        $frontendInputElm = $form->getElement('frontend_input');
        $additionalTypes = array(
            array(
                'value' => 'image',
                'label' => Mage::helper('easylife_news')->__('Image')
            ),
            array(
                'value' => 'file',
                'label' => Mage::helper('easylife_news')->__('File')
            )
        );
        $response = new Varien_Object();
        $response->setTypes(array());
        Mage::dispatchEvent('adminhtml_article_attribute_types', array('response'=>$response));
        $_disabledTypes = array();
        $_hiddenFields = array();
        foreach ($response->getTypes() as $type) {
            $additionalTypes[] = $type;
            if (isset($type['hide_fields'])) {
                $_hiddenFields[$type['value']] = $type['hide_fields'];
            }
            if (isset($type['disabled_types'])) {
                $_disabledTypes[$type['value']] = $type['disabled_types'];
            }
        }
        Mage::register('attribute_type_hidden_fields', $_hiddenFields);
        Mage::register('attribute_type_disabled_types', $_disabledTypes);

        $frontendInputValues = array_merge($frontendInputElm->getValues(), $additionalTypes);
        $frontendInputElm->setValues($frontendInputValues);

        $yesnoSource = Mage::getModel('adminhtml/system_config_source_yesno')->toOptionArray();

        $scopes = array(
            Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_STORE =>Mage::helper('easylife_news')->__('Store View'),
            Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_WEBSITE =>Mage::helper('easylife_news')->__('Website'),
            Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_GLOBAL =>Mage::helper('easylife_news')->__('Global'),
        );

        $fieldset->addField('is_global', 'select', array(
            'name'  => 'is_global',
            'label' => Mage::helper('easylife_news')->__('Scope'),
            'title' => Mage::helper('easylife_news')->__('Scope'),
            'note'  => Mage::helper('easylife_news')->__('Declare attribute value saving scope'),
            'values'=> $scopes
        ), 'attribute_code');
        $fieldset->addField('position', 'text', array(
            'name'  => 'position',
            'label' => Mage::helper('easylife_news')->__('Position'),
            'title' => Mage::helper('easylife_news')->__('Position'),
            'note'  => Mage::helper('easylife_news')->__('Position in the admin form'),
        ), 'is_global');
        $fieldset->addField('note', 'textarea', array(
            'name'  => 'note',
            'label' => Mage::helper('easylife_news')->__('Note'),
            'title' => Mage::helper('easylife_news')->__('Note'),
            'note'  => Mage::helper('easylife_news')->__('Text to appear below the input.'),
        ), 'position');

        $fieldset->removeField('default_value_text');
        $fieldset->removeField('default_value_yesno');
        $fieldset->removeField('default_value_date');
        $fieldset->removeField('default_value_textarea');
        $fieldset->removeField('is_unique');
        // frontend properties fieldset
        $fieldset = $form->addFieldset('front_fieldset', array('legend'=>Mage::helper('easylife_news')->__('Frontend Properties')));


        $fieldset->addField('is_wysiwyg_enabled', 'select', array(
            'name' => 'is_wysiwyg_enabled',
            'label' => Mage::helper('easylife_news')->__('Enable WYSIWYG'),
            'title' => Mage::helper('easylife_news')->__('Enable WYSIWYG'),
            'values' => $yesnoSource,
        ));
        Mage::dispatchEvent('easylife_news_adminhtml_article_attribute_edit_prepare_form', array(
            'form'      => $form,
            'attribute' => $attributeObject
        ));
        return $this;
    }
}
```

`app/code/local/Easylife/News/Block/Adminhtml/Attribute/Edit/Tab/Options.php` - tab for rendering attribute options

```
<?php
class Easylife_News_Block_Adminhtml_Article_Attribute_Edit_Tab_Options
    extends Mage_Eav_Block_Adminhtml_Attribute_Edit_Options_Abstract {

}
```

`app/code/local/Easylife/News/Block/Adminhtml/News/Helper/Form/Wysiwyg/Content.php` - helper block for WYSIWYG elements

```
<?php
class Easylife_News_Block_Adminhtml_News_Helper_Form_Wysiwyg_Content
    extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form {
    protected function _prepareForm(){
        $form = new Varien_Data_Form(array('id' => 'wysiwyg_edit_form', 'action' => $this->getData('action'), 'method' => 'post'));
        $config['document_base_url']     = $this->getData('store_media_url');
        $config['store_id']              = $this->getData('store_id');
        $config['add_variables']         = false;
        $config['add_widgets']           = false;
        $config['add_directives']        = true;
        $config['use_container']         = true;
        $config['container_class']       = 'hor-scroll';
        $editorConfig = Mage::getSingleton('cms/wysiwyg_config')->getConfig($config);
        $editorConfig->setData('files_browser_window_url', Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/url')->getUrl('adminhtml/cms_wysiwyg_images/index'));
        $form->addField($this->getData('editor_element_id'), 'editor', array(
            'name'      => 'content',
            'style'     => 'width:725px;height:460px',
            'required'  => true,
            'force_load' => true,
            'config'    => $editorConfig
        ));
        $this->setForm($form);
        return parent::_prepareForm();
    }
}
```

now look for part 4.

Comment: hi @marius I m getting Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function setAttributes() on boolean in /magento/app/code/local/Easylife/News/Block/Adminhtml/Article/Edit/Tabs.php:21

Comment: Make sure the class `Easylife_News_Block_Adminhtml_Article_Edit_Tab_Attributes` exists and it's in the right place.

Comment: yes its there with proper folder structure

Comment: make sure the `<blocks>` tag exists in your config.xml file. For some reason the method call `getBlock('easylife_news/adminhtml_article_edit_tab_attributes')` returns false. this means that the block does not exist or it cannot be instantiated. TO avoid problems like this I recommend you to use this tool https://github.com/tzyganu/UMC1.9 to create your eav entity module.

Comment: block tag is also added in config.xml

Answer (score 9):

**Part 4**

`app/code/local/Easylife/News/Block/Adminhtml/News/Renderer/Fieldset/Element.php` - fieldset element renderer.

```
<?php
class Easylife_News_Block_Adminhtml_News_Renderer_Fieldset_Element
    extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form_Renderer_Fieldset_Element {
    protected function _construct() {
        $this->setTemplate('easylife_news/form/renderer/fieldset/element.phtml');
    }
    public function getDataObject() {
        return $this->getElement()->getForm()->getDataObject();
    }

    public function getAttribute() {
        return $this->getElement()->getEntityAttribute();
    }

    public function getAttributeCode(){
        return $this->getAttribute()->getAttributeCode();
    }
    public function canDisplayUseDefault(){
        if ($attribute = $this->getAttribute()) {
            if (!$this->isScopeGlobal($attribute)
                && $this->getDataObject()
                && $this->getDataObject()->getId()
                && $this->getDataObject()->getStoreId()) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
    public function usedDefault(){
        $defaultValue = $this->getDataObject()->getAttributeDefaultValue($this->getAttribute()->getAttributeCode());
        return !$defaultValue;
    }
    public function checkFieldDisable(){
        if ($this->canDisplayUseDefault() && $this->usedDefault()) {
            $this->getElement()->setDisabled(true);
        }
        return $this;
    }
    public function getScopeLabel(){
        $html = '';
        $attribute = $this->getElement()->getEntityAttribute();
        if (!$attribute || Mage::app()->isSingleStoreMode()) {
            return $html;
        }
        if ($this->isScopeGlobal($attribute)) {
            $html.= Mage::helper('easylife_news')->__('[GLOBAL]');
        }
        elseif ($this->isScopeWebsite($attribute)) {
            $html.= Mage::helper('easylife_news')->__('[WEBSITE]');
        }
        elseif ($this->isScopeStore($attribute)) {
            $html.= Mage::helper('easylife_news')->__('[STORE VIEW]');
        }
        return $html;
    }
    public function getElementLabelHtml(){
        return $this->getElement()->getLabelHtml();
    }

    public function getElementHtml(){
        return $this->getElement()->getElementHtml();
    }

    public function isScopeGlobal($attribute){
        return $attribute->getIsGlobal() == 1;
    }
    public function isScopeWebsite($attribute){
        return $attribute->getIsGlobal() == 2;
    }
    public function isScopeStore($attribute){
        return !$this->isScopeGlobal($attribute) && !$this->isScopeWebsite($attribute);
    }
}
```

`app/code/local/Easylife/News/Block/Article/List.php` - the article frontend list block.

```
<?php
class Easylife_News_Block_Article_List
    extends Mage_Core_Block_Template {
     public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
         $articles = Mage::getResourceModel('easylife_news/article_collection')
                         ->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())
                         ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                         ->addAttributeToFilter('status', 1);
        $articles->setOrder('title', 'asc');
        $this->setArticles($articles);
    }
    protected function _prepareLayout(){
        parent::_prepareLayout();
        $pager = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('page/html_pager', 'easylife_news.article.html.pager')
            ->setCollection($this->getArticles());
        $this->setChild('pager', $pager);
        $this->getArticles()->load();
        return $this;
    }
    public function getPagerHtml(){
        return $this->getChildHtml('pager');
    }
}
```

`app/code/local/Easylife/News/Block/Article/View.php` - the article frontend view block.

```
<?php
class Easylife_News_Block_Article_View
    extends Mage_Core_Block_Template {
    public function getCurrentArticle(){
        return Mage::registry('current_article');
    }
}
```

`app/code/local/Easylife/News/Block/Article/Rss.php` - the article frontend RSS block.

```
<?php
class Easylife_News_Block_Article_Rss
    extends Mage_Rss_Block_Abstract {
    const CACHE_TAG = 'block_html_news_article_rss';
    protected function _construct(){
        $this->setCacheTags(array(self::CACHE_TAG));
        /*
        * setting cache to save the rss for 10 minutes
        */
        $this->setCacheKey('easylife_news_article_rss');
        $this->setCacheLifetime(600);
    }
    protected function _toHtml(){
        $url = Mage::helper('easylife_news/article')->getArticlesUrl();
        $title = Mage::helper('easylife_news')->__('Articles');
        $rssObj = Mage::getModel('rss/rss');
        $data = array(
            'title' => $title,
            'description' => $title,
            'link'=> $url,
            'charset' => 'UTF-8',
        );
        $rssObj->_addHeader($data);
        $collection = Mage::getModel('easylife_news/article')->getCollection()
            ->addFieldToFilter('status', 1)
            ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
            ->addAttributeToFilter('in_rss', 1)
            ->setOrder('created_at');
        $collection->load();
        foreach ($collection as $item){
            $description = '<p>';
            $description .= '<div>'.Mage::helper('easylife_news')->__('Title').': '.$item->getTitle().'</div>';
            $description .= '<div>'.Mage::helper('easylife_news')->__('Short description').': '.$item->getShortDescription().'</div>';
            $description .= '<div>'.Mage::helper('easylife_news')->__('Description').': '.$item->getDescription().'</div>';
            $description .= '<div>'.Mage::helper('easylife_news')->__('Publish Date').': '.Mage::helper('core')->formatDate($item->getPublishDate(), 'full').'</div>';
            $description .= '</p>';
            $data = array(
                'title'=>$item->getTitle(),
                'link'=>$item->getArticleUrl(),
                'description' => $description
            );
            $rssObj->_addEntry($data);
        }
        return $rssObj->createRssXml();
    }
}
```

Now the **Router** for url rewrites.

`app/code/local/Easylife/News/Controller/Router.php` - the router

```
<?php 
class Easylife_News_Controller_Router
    extends Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Abstract {
    public function initControllerRouters($observer){
        $front = $observer->getEvent()->getFront();
        $front->addRouter('easylife_news', $this);
        return $this;
    }
    public function match(Zend_Controller_Request_Http $request){
        if (!Mage::isInstalled()) {
            Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getResponse()
                ->setRedirect(Mage::getUrl('install'))
                ->sendResponse();
            exit;
        }
        $urlKey = trim($request->getPathInfo(), '/');
        $check = array(); //you can add here multiple entities
        $check['article'] = new Varien_Object(array(
            'prefix'        => Mage::getStoreConfig('easylife_news/article/url_prefix'),
            'suffix'        => Mage::getStoreConfig('easylife_news/article/url_suffix'),
            'model'         =>'easylife_news/article',
            'controller'    => 'article',
            'action'        => 'view',
            'param'         => 'id',
        ));
        foreach ($check as $key=>$settings) {
            if ($settings['prefix']){
                $parts = explode('/', $urlKey);
                if ($parts[0] != $settings['prefix'] || count($parts) != 2){
                    continue;
                }
                $urlKey = $parts[1];
            }
            if ($settings['suffix']){
                $urlKey = substr($urlKey, 0 , -strlen($settings['suffix']) - 1);
            }
            $model = Mage::getModel($settings->getModel());
            $id = $model->checkUrlKey($urlKey, Mage::app()->getStore()->getId());
            if ($id){
                if ($settings->getCheckPath() && !$model->load($id)->getStatusPath()) {
                    continue;
                }
                $request->setModuleName('news')
                    ->setControllerName($settings->getController())
                    ->setActionName($settings->getAction())
                    ->setParam($settings->getParam(), $id);
                $request->setAlias(
                    Mage_Core_Model_Url_Rewrite::REWRITE_REQUEST_PATH_ALIAS,
                    $urlKey
                );
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Now the **controllers**

`app/code/local/Easylife/News/controllers/Adminhtml/News/ArticleController.php`

```
<?php
class Easylife_News_Adminhtml_News_ArticleController
    extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action {
    protected function _construct(){
        $this->setUsedModuleName('Easylife_News');
    }
    protected function _initArticle(){
        $this->_title($this->__('News'))
             ->_title($this->__('Manage Articles'));

        $articleId  = (int) $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
        $article    = Mage::getModel('easylife_news/article')
            ->setStoreId($this->getRequest()->getParam('store', 0));

        if ($articleId) {
            $article->load($articleId);
        }
        Mage::register('current_article', $article);
        return $article;
    }
    public function indexAction(){
        $this->_title($this->__('News'))
             ->_title($this->__('Manage Articles'));
        $this->loadLayout();
        $this->renderLayout();
    }
    public function newAction(){
        $this->_forward('edit');
    }
    public function editAction(){
        $articleId  = (int) $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');

        $article = $this->_initArticle();
        if ($articleId && !$article->getId()) {
            $this->_getSession()->addError(Mage::helper('easylife_news')->__('This article no longer exists.'));
            $this->_redirect('*/*/');
            return;
        }
        if ($data = Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->getArticleData(true)){
            $article->setData($data);
        }
        $this->_title($article->getTitle());
        Mage::dispatchEvent('easylife_news_article_edit_action', array('article' => $article));
        $this->loadLayout();
        if ($article->getId()){
            if (!Mage::app()->isSingleStoreMode() && ($switchBlock = $this->getLayout()->getBlock('store_switcher'))) {
                $switchBlock->setDefaultStoreName(Mage::helper('easylife_news')->__('Default Values'))
                    ->setSwitchUrl($this->getUrl('*/*/*', array('_current'=>true, 'active_tab'=>null, 'tab' => null, 'store'=>null)));
            }
        }
        else{
            $this->getLayout()->getBlock('left')->unsetChild('store_switcher');
        }
        $this->getLayout()->getBlock('head')->setCanLoadExtJs(true);
        $this->renderLayout();
    }
    public function saveAction(){
        $storeId        = $this->getRequest()->getParam('store');
        $redirectBack   = $this->getRequest()->getParam('back', false);
        $articleId      = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
        $isEdit         = (int)($this->getRequest()->getParam('id') != null);
        $data = $this->getRequest()->getPost();
        if ($data) {
            $article    = $this->_initArticle();
            $articleData = $this->getRequest()->getPost('article', array());
            $article->addData($articleData);
            $article->setAttributeSetId($article->getDefaultAttributeSetId());
            if ($useDefaults = $this->getRequest()->getPost('use_default')) {
                foreach ($useDefaults as $attributeCode) {
                    $article->setData($attributeCode, false);
                }
            }
            try {
                $article->save();
                $articleId = $article->getId();
                $this->_getSession()->addSuccess(Mage::helper('easylife_news')->__('Article was saved'));
            }
            catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) {
                Mage::logException($e);
                $this->_getSession()->addError($e->getMessage())
                    ->setArticleData($articleData);
                $redirectBack = true;
            }
            catch (Exception $e){
                Mage::logException($e);
                $this->_getSession()->addError(Mage::helper('easylife_news')->__('Error saving article'))
                    ->setArticleData($articleData);
                $redirectBack = true;
            }
        }
        if ($redirectBack) {
            $this->_redirect('*/*/edit', array(
                'id'    => $articleId,
                '_current'=>true
            ));
        }
        else {
            $this->_redirect('*/*/', array('store'=>$storeId));
        }
    }
    public function deleteAction(){
        if ($id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id')) {
            $article = Mage::getModel('easylife_news/article')->load($id);
            try {
                $article->delete();
                $this->_getSession()->addSuccess(Mage::helper('easylife_news')->__('The articles has been deleted.'));
            }
            catch (Exception $e) {
                $this->_getSession()->addError($e->getMessage());
            }
        }
        $this->getResponse()->setRedirect($this->getUrl('*/*/', array('store'=>$this->getRequest()->getParam('store'))));
    }
    public function massDeleteAction() {
        $articleIds = $this->getRequest()->getParam('article');
        if (!is_array($articleIds)) {
            $this->_getSession()->addError($this->__('Please select articles.'));
        }
        else {
            try {
                foreach ($articleIds as $articleId) {
                    $article = Mage::getSingleton('easylife_news/article')->load($articleId);
                    Mage::dispatchEvent('easylife_news_controller_article_delete', array('article' => $article));
                    $article->delete();
                }
                $this->_getSession()->addSuccess(
                    Mage::helper('easylife_news')->__('Total of %d record(s) have been deleted.', count($articleIds))
                );
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                $this->_getSession()->addError($e->getMessage());
            }
        }
        $this->_redirect('*/*/index');
    }
    public function massStatusAction(){
        $articleIds = $this->getRequest()->getParam('article');
        if(!is_array($articleIds)) {
            Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError(Mage::helper('easylife_news')->__('Please select articles.'));
        }
        else {
            try {
                foreach ($articleIds as $articleId) {
                $article = Mage::getSingleton('easylife_news/article')->load($articleId)
                            ->setStatus($this->getRequest()->getParam('status'))
                            ->setIsMassupdate(true)
                            ->save();
                }
                $this->_getSession()->addSuccess($this->__('Total of %d articles were successfully updated.', count($articleIds)));
            }
            catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e){
                Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError($e->getMessage());
            }
            catch (Exception $e) {
                Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError(Mage::helper('easylife_news')->__('There was an error updating articles.'));
                Mage::logException($e);
            }
        }
        $this->_redirect('*/*/index');
    }
    public function gridAction(){
        $this->loadLayout();
        $this->renderLayout();
    }
     protected function _isAllowed(){
        return Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->isAllowed('cms/easylife_news/article');
    }

    public function exportCsvAction(){
        $fileName   = 'articles.csv';
        $content    = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('easylife_news/adminhtml_article_grid')
            ->getCsvFile();
        $this->_prepareDownloadResponse($fileName, $content);
    }
    public function exportExcelAction(){
        $fileName   = 'article.xls';
        $content    = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('easylife_news/adminhtml_article_grid')
            ->getExcelFile();
        $this->_prepareDownloadResponse($fileName, $content);
    }
    public function exportXmlAction(){
        $fileName   = 'article.xml';
        $content    = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('easylife_news/adminhtml_article_grid')
            ->getXml();
        $this->_prepareDownloadResponse($fileName, $content);
    }
    public function wysiwygAction() {
        $elementId = $this->getRequest()->getParam('element_id', md5(microtime()));
        $storeId = $this->getRequest()->getParam('store_id', 0);
        $storeMediaUrl = Mage::app()->getStore($storeId)->getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_MEDIA);

        $content = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('easylife_news/adminhtml_news_helper_form_wysiwyg_content', '', array(
            'editor_element_id' => $elementId,
            'store_id'          => $storeId,
            'store_media_url'   => $storeMediaUrl,
        ));
        $this->getResponse()->setBody($content->toHtml());
    }
}
```

`app/code/local/Easylife/News/controllers/ArticleController.php` - the frontend article controller

```
<?php
class Easylife_News_ArticleController
    extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action {
    public function indexAction(){
         $this->loadLayout();
         $this->_initLayoutMessages('catalog/session');
         $this->_initLayoutMessages('customer/session');
         $this->_initLayoutMessages('checkout/session');
         if (Mage::helper('easylife_news/article')->getUseBreadcrumbs()){
             if ($breadcrumbBlock = $this->getLayout()->getBlock('breadcrumbs')){
                 $breadcrumbBlock->addCrumb('home', array(
                            'label'    => Mage::helper('easylife_news')->__('Home'),
                            'link'     => Mage::getUrl(),
                        )
                 );
                 $breadcrumbBlock->addCrumb('articles', array(
                            'label'    => Mage::helper('easylife_news')->__('Articles'),
                            'link'    => '',
                    )
                 );
             }
         }
        $headBlock = $this->getLayout()->getBlock('head');
        if ($headBlock) {
            $headBlock->setTitle(Mage::getStoreConfig('easylife_news/article/meta_title'));
            $headBlock->setKeywords(Mage::getStoreConfig('easylife_news/article/meta_keywords'));
            $headBlock->setDescription(Mage::getStoreConfig('easylife_news/article/meta_description'));
        }
        $this->renderLayout();
    }
    protected function _initArticle(){
        $articleId   = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id', 0);
        $article     = Mage::getModel('easylife_news/article')
                        ->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())
                        ->load($articleId);
        if (!$article->getId()){
            return false;
        }
        elseif (!$article->getStatus()){
            return false;
        }
        return $article;
    }
    public function viewAction(){
        $article = $this->_initArticle();
        if (!$article) {
            $this->_forward('no-route');
            return;
        }
        Mage::register('current_article', $article);
        $this->loadLayout();
        $this->_initLayoutMessages('catalog/session');
        $this->_initLayoutMessages('customer/session');
        $this->_initLayoutMessages('checkout/session');
        if ($root = $this->getLayout()->getBlock('root')) {
            $root->addBodyClass('news-article news-article' . $article->getId());
        }
        if (Mage::helper('easylife_news/article')->getUseBreadcrumbs()){
            if ($breadcrumbBlock = $this->getLayout()->getBlock('breadcrumbs')){
                $breadcrumbBlock->addCrumb('home', array(
                            'label'    => Mage::helper('easylife_news')->__('Home'),
                            'link'     => Mage::getUrl(),
                        )
                );
                $breadcrumbBlock->addCrumb('articles', array(
                            'label'    => Mage::helper('easylife_news')->__('Articles'),
                            'link'    => Mage::helper('easylife_news/article')->getArticlesUrl(),
                    )
                );
                $breadcrumbBlock->addCrumb('article', array(
                            'label'    => $article->getTitle(),
                            'link'    => '',
                    )
                );
            }
        }
        $headBlock = $this->getLayout()->getBlock('head');
        if ($headBlock) {
            if ($article->getMetaTitle()){
                $headBlock->setTitle($article->getMetaTitle());
            }
            else{
                $headBlock->setTitle($article->getTitle());
            }
            $headBlock->setKeywords($article->getMetaKeywords());
            $headBlock->setDescription($article->getMetaDescription());
        }
        $this->renderLayout();
    }
    public function rssAction(){
        if (Mage::helper('easylife_news/article')->isRssEnabled()) {
            $this->getResponse()->setHeader('Content-type', 'text/xml; charset=UTF-8');
            $this->loadLayout(false);
            $this->renderLayout();
        }
        else {
            $this->getResponse()->setHeader('HTTP/1.1','404 Not Found');
            $this->getResponse()->setHeader('Status','404 File not found');
            $this->_forward('nofeed','index','rss');
        }
    }
}
```

Look for part 5

Comment: If I have an Article with an Image attribute and add additional validation to an Article `_beforeSave` method, so that it throws a `Mage_Core_Exception`. I get Array to String conversion errors from Image when editing. I believe this is because the call to `setArticleData` does not take into account, the image data being sent in as an array, especially when you are Editing. Is this a mistake in your code or my approach at handling additional validation? FYI My current work around involves me doing `unset($articleData['image']);` before `setArticleData`

Answer (score 7):

**Part 5**

`app/code/local/Easylife/News/controllers/Adminhtml/News/Article/AttributeController.php` - the attribute controller

```
<?php
class Easylife_News_Adminhtml_News_Article_AttributeController
    extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action {
    protected $_entityTypeId;
    public function preDispatch() {
        parent::preDispatch();
        $this->_entityTypeId = Mage::getModel('eav/entity')->setType(Easylife_News_Model_Article::ENTITY)->getTypeId();
    }
    protected function _initAction(){
        $this->_title(Mage::helper('easylife_news')->__('Article'))
             ->_title(Mage::helper('easylife_news')->__('Attributes'))
             ->_title(Mage::helper('easylife_news')->__('Manage Attributes'));

        $this->loadLayout()
            ->_setActiveMenu('cms/easylife_news/article_attributes');
        return $this;
    }
    public function indexAction(){
        $this->_initAction()
            ->renderLayout();
    }
    public function newAction(){
        $this->_forward('edit');
    }

    public function editAction(){
        $id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('attribute_id');
        $model = Mage::getModel('easylife_news/resource_eav_attribute')
            ->setEntityTypeId($this->_entityTypeId);
        if ($id) {
            $model->load($id);
            if (! $model->getId()) {
                Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError(
                    Mage::helper('easylife_news')->__('This article attribute no longer exists'));
                $this->_redirect('*/*/');
                return;
            }
            // entity type check
            if ($model->getEntityTypeId() != $this->_entityTypeId) {
                Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError(
                    Mage::helper('easylife_news')->__('This article attribute cannot be edited.'));
                $this->_redirect('*/*/');
                return;
            }
        }
        // set entered data if was error when we do save
        $data = Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->getAttributeData(true);
        if (! empty($data)) {
            $model->addData($data);
        }
        Mage::register('entity_attribute', $model);
        $this->_initAction();
        $this->_title($id ? $model->getName() : Mage::helper('easylife_news')->__('New Article Attribute'));
        $item = $id ? Mage::helper('easylife_news')->__('Edit Article Attribute')
                    : Mage::helper('easylife_news')->__('New Article Attribute');
        $this->_addBreadcrumb($item, $item);
        $this->renderLayout();
    }

    public function validateAction(){
        $response = new Varien_Object();
        $response->setError(false);

        $attributeCode  = $this->getRequest()->getParam('attribute_code');
        $attributeId    = $this->getRequest()->getParam('attribute_id');
        $attribute = Mage::getModel('easylife_news/attribute')
            ->loadByCode($this->_entityTypeId, $attributeCode);
        if ($attribute->getId() && !$attributeId) {
            Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError(
                Mage::helper('easylife_news')->__('Attribute with the same code already exists'));
            $this->_initLayoutMessages('adminhtml/session');
            $response->setError(true);
            $response->setMessage($this->getLayout()->getMessagesBlock()->getGroupedHtml());
        }
        $this->getResponse()->setBody($response->toJson());
    }
    protected function _filterPostData($data){
        if ($data) {
            $helper = Mage::helper('easylife_news');
            //labels
            foreach ($data['frontend_label'] as & $value) {
                if ($value) {
                    $value = $helper->stripTags($value);
                }
            }
            //options
            if (!empty($data['option']['value'])) {
                foreach ($data['option']['value'] as &$options) {
                    foreach ($options as &$label) {
                        $label = $helper->stripTags($label);
                    }
                }
            }
            //default value
            if (!empty($data['default_value'])) {
                $data['default_value'] = $helper->stripTags($data['default_value']);
            }
            if (!empty($data['default_value_text'])) {
                $data['default_value_text'] = $helper->stripTags($data['default_value_text']);
            }
            if (!empty($data['default_value_textarea'])) {
                $data['default_value_textarea'] = $helper->stripTags($data['default_value_textarea']);
            }
        }
        return $data;
    }
    public function saveAction(){
        $data = $this->getRequest()->getPost();
        if ($data) {
            $session = Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session');
            $redirectBack   = $this->getRequest()->getParam('back', false);
            $model = Mage::getModel('easylife_news/resource_eav_attribute');
            $helper = Mage::helper('easylife_news/article');
            $id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('attribute_id');
            //validate attribute_code
            if (isset($data['attribute_code'])) {
                $validatorAttrCode = new Zend_Validate_Regex(array('pattern' => '/^[a-z_0-9]{1,255}$/'));
                if (!$validatorAttrCode->isValid($data['attribute_code'])) {
                    $session->addError(
                        Mage::helper('easylife_news')->__('Attribute code is invalid. Please use only letters (a-z), numbers (0-9) or underscore(_) in this field, first character should be a letter.'));
                    $this->_redirect('*/*/edit', array('attribute_id' => $id, '_current' => true));
                    return;
                }
            }
            if ($id) {
                $model->load($id);
                if (!$model->getId()) {
                    $session->addError(
                        Mage::helper('easylife_news')->__('This attribute no longer exists'));
                    $this->_redirect('*/*/');
                    return;
                }

                // entity type check
                if ($model->getEntityTypeId() != $this->_entityTypeId) {
                    $session->addError(
                        Mage::helper('easylife_news')->__('This attribute cannot be updated.'));
                    $session->setAttributeData($data);
                    $this->_redirect('*/*/');
                    return;
                }

                $data['attribute_code'] = $model->getAttributeCode();
                $data['is_user_defined'] = $model->getIsUserDefined();
                $data['frontend_input'] = $model->getFrontendInput();
            } else {
                $data['source_model'] = $helper->getAttributeSourceModelByInputType($data['frontend_input']);
                $data['backend_model'] = $helper->getAttributeBackendModelByInputType($data['frontend_input']);
            }

            if (is_null($model->getIsUserDefined()) || $model->getIsUserDefined() != 0) {
                $data['backend_type'] = $model->getBackendTypeByInput($data['frontend_input']);
            }
            $defaultValueField = $model->getDefaultValueByInput($data['frontend_input']);
            if ($defaultValueField) {
                $data['default_value'] = $this->getRequest()->getParam($defaultValueField);
            }
            //filter
            $data = $this->_filterPostData($data);
            $model->addData($data);
            if (!$id) {
                $model->setEntityTypeId($this->_entityTypeId);
                $model->setIsUserDefined(1);
                $model->setIsVisible(1);
            }
            try {
                $model->save();
                $session->addSuccess(
                    Mage::helper('easylife_news')->__('The article attribute has been saved.'));

                /**
                 * Clear translation cache because attribute labels are stored in translation
                 */
                Mage::app()->cleanCache(array(Mage_Core_Model_Translate::CACHE_TAG));
                $session->setAttributeData(false);
                if ($redirectBack) {
                    $this->_redirect('*/*/edit', array('attribute_id' => $model->getId(),'_current'=>true));
                } else {
                    $this->_redirect('*/*/', array());
                }
                return;
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                $session->addError($e->getMessage());
                $session->setAttributeData($data);
                $this->_redirect('*/*/edit', array('attribute_id' => $id, '_current' => true));
                return;
            }
        }
        $this->_redirect('*/*/');
    }
    public function deleteAction(){
        if ($id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('attribute_id')) {
            $model = Mage::getModel('easylife_news/resource_eav_attribute');

            // entity type check
            $model->load($id);
            if ($model->getEntityTypeId() != $this->_entityTypeId) {
                Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError(
                    Mage::helper('easylife_news')->__('This attribute cannot be deleted.'));
                $this->_redirect('*/*/');
                return;
            }
            try {
                $model->delete();
                Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addSuccess(
                    Mage::helper('easylife_news')->__('The article attribute has been deleted.'));
                $this->_redirect('*/*/');
                return;
            }
            catch (Exception $e) {
                Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError($e->getMessage());
                $this->_redirect('*/*/edit', array('attribute_id' => $this->getRequest()->getParam('attribute_id')));
                return;
            }
        }
        Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError(
            Mage::helper('easylife_news')->__('Unable to find an attribute to delete.'));
        $this->_redirect('*/*/');
    }
    protected function _isAllowed(){
        return Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->isAllowed('cms/easylife_news/article_attributes');
    }
}
```

Now the **helpers**:

`app/code/local/Easylife/News/Helper/Data.php` - the main helper

```
<?php
class Easylife_News_Helper_Data
    extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract {
    public function convertOptions($options){
        $converted = array();
        foreach ($options as $option){
            if (isset($option['value']) && !is_array($option['value']) && isset($option['label']) && !is_array($option['label'])){
                $converted[$option['value']] = $option['label'];
            }
        }
        return $converted;
    }
}
```

`app/code/local/Easylife/News/Helper/Article.php` - article helper

```
<?php 
class Easylife_News_Helper_Article
    extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract {
    public function getArticlesUrl(){
        return Mage::getUrl('easylife_news/article/index');
    }
    public function getUseBreadcrumbs(){
        return Mage::getStoreConfigFlag('easylife_news/article/breadcrumbs');
    }
    public function isRssEnabled(){
        return  Mage::getStoreConfigFlag('rss/config/active') && Mage::getStoreConfigFlag('easylife_news/article/rss');
    }
    public function getRssUrl(){
        return Mage::getUrl('easylife_news/article/rss');
    }
    public function getFileBaseDir(){
        return Mage::getBaseDir('media').DS.'article'.DS.'file';
    }
    public function getFileBaseUrl(){
        return Mage::getBaseUrl('media').'article'.'/'.'file';
    }
    public function getAttributeSourceModelByInputType($inputType){
        $inputTypes = $this->getAttributeInputTypes();
        if (!empty($inputTypes[$inputType]['source_model'])) {
            return $inputTypes[$inputType]['source_model'];
        }
        return null;
    }
    public function getAttributeInputTypes($inputType = null){
        $inputTypes = array(
            'multiselect'   => array(
                'backend_model'     => 'eav/entity_attribute_backend_array'
            ),
            'boolean'       => array(
                'source_model'      => 'eav/entity_attribute_source_boolean'
            ),
            'file'          => array(
                'backend_model'     => 'easylife_news/article_attribute_backend_file'
            ),
            'image'         => array(
                'backend_model'     => 'easylife_news/article_attribute_backend_image'
            ),
        );

        if (is_null($inputType)) {
            return $inputTypes;
        } else if (isset($inputTypes[$inputType])) {
            return $inputTypes[$inputType];
        }
        return array();
    }
    public function getAttributeBackendModelByInputType($inputType){
        $inputTypes = $this->getAttributeInputTypes();
        if (!empty($inputTypes[$inputType]['backend_model'])) {
            return $inputTypes[$inputType]['backend_model'];
        }
        return null;
    }
    public function articleAttribute($article, $attributeHtml, $attributeName){
        $attribute = Mage::getSingleton('eav/config')->getAttribute(Easylife_News_Model_Article::ENTITY, $attributeName);
        if ($attribute && $attribute->getId() && !$attribute->getIsWysiwygEnabled()) {
            if ($attribute->getFrontendInput() == 'textarea') {
                $attributeHtml = nl2br($attributeHtml);
            }
        }
        if ($attribute->getIsWysiwygEnabled()) {
            $attributeHtml = $this->_getTemplateProcessor()->filter($attributeHtml);
        }
        return $attributeHtml;
    }
    protected function _getTemplateProcessor(){
        if (null === $this->_templateProcessor) {
            $this->_templateProcessor = Mage::helper('catalog')->getPageTemplateProcessor();
        }
        return $this->_templateProcessor;
    }
}
```

`app/code/local/Easylife/News/Helper/Image/Abstract.php` - abstract image helper

```
<?php
abstract class Easylife_News_Helper_Image_Abstract
    extends Mage_Core_Helper_Data {
    protected $_placeholder     = '';
    protected $_subdir          = '';
    protected $_imageProcessor     = null;
    protected $_image             = null;
    protected $_openError         = "";
    protected $_keepFrame       = false;
    protected $_keepAspectRatio = true;
    protected $_constrainOnly   = true;
    protected $_adaptiveResize  = 'center'; // false|center|top|bottom
    protected $_width           = null;
    protected $_height          = null;
    protected $_scheduledResize = null;
    protected $_resized         = false;
    protected $_adaptiveResizePositions = array(
        'center'=>array(0.5,0.5),
        'top'   =>array(1,0),
        'bottom'=>array(0,1)
    );
    protected $_resizeFolderName = 'cache';
    public function getImageBaseDir(){
        return Mage::getBaseDir('media').DS.$this->_subdir.DS.'image';
    }
    public function getImageBaseUrl(){
        return Mage::getBaseUrl('media').$this->_subdir.'/'.'image';
    }
    public function init(Varien_Object $object, $imageField = 'image'){
        $this->_imageProcessor = null;
        $this->_image = $object->getDataUsingMethod($imageField);
        if(!$this->_image) {
            $this->_image = '/'.$this->_placeholder;
        }
        $this->_widht = null;
        $this->_height = null;
        $this->_scheduledResize = false;
        $this->_resized = false;
        $this->_adaptiveResize = 'center';

        try{
            $this->_getImageProcessor()->open($this->getImageBaseDir().$this->_image);
        }
        catch (Exception $e){
            $this->_openError = $e->getMessage();
            try{
                $this->_getImageProcessor()->open(Mage::getDesign()->getSkinUrl($this->_placeholder));
                $this->_image = '/'.$this->_placeholder;
            }
            catch(Exception $e) {
                $this->_openError .= "\n".$e->getMessage();
                $this->_image = null;
            }
        }
        return $this;
    }
    protected function _getImageProcessor() {
        if (is_null($this->_imageProcessor)) {
            $this->_imageProcessor = Varien_Image_Adapter::factory('GD2');
            $this->_imageProcessor->keepFrame($this->_keepFrame);
            $this->_imageProcessor->keepAspectRatio($this->_keepAspectRatio);
            $this->_imageProcessor->constrainOnly($this->_constrainOnly);
        }
        return $this->_imageProcessor;
    }
    public function keepAspectRatio($value = null){
        if (null !== $value) {
            $this->_getImageProcessor()->keepAspectRatio($value);
            return $this;
        }
        else {
            return $this->_getImageProcessor()->keepAspectRatio();
        }
    }
    public function keepFrame($value = null){
        if (null !== $value) {
            $this->_getImageProcessor()->keepFrame($value);
            return $this;
        }
        else {
            return $this->_getImageProcessor()->keepFrame();
        }
    }
    public function keepTransparency($value = null){
        if (null !== $value) {
            $this->_getImageProcessor()->keepTransparency($value);
            return $this;
        }
        else {
            return $this->_getImageProcessor()->keepTransparency();
        }
    }
    public function adaptiveResize($value = null){
        if (null !== $value) {
            $this->_adaptiveResize = $value;
            if($value) {
                $this->keepFrame(false);
            }
            return $this;
        }
        else {
            return $this->_adaptiveResize;
        }
    }
    public function constrainOnly($value = null){
       if (null !== $value) {
            $this->_getImageProcessor()->constrainOnly($value);
            return $this;
        }
        else {
            return $this->_getImageProcessor()->constrainOnly();
        }
    }
    public function quality($value = null){
        if (null !== $value) {
            $this->_getImageProcessor()->quality($value);
            return $this;
        }
        else {
            return $this->_getImageProcessor()->quality();
        }
    }
    public function backgroundColor($value = null){
        if (null !== $value) {
            $this->_getImageProcessor()-> backgroundColor($value);
            return $this;
        }
        else {
            return $this->_getImageProcessor()-> backgroundColor();
        }
    }
    public function resize($width = null, $height = null) {
        $this->_scheduledResize = true;
        $this->_width  = $width;
        $this->_height = $height;
        return $this;
    }
    protected function _getDestinationImagePrefix() {
        if(!$this->_image) {
            return $this;
        }
        $imageRealPath = "";
        if($this->_scheduledResize) {
            $width  = $this->_width;
            $height = $this->_height;
            $adaptive   = $this->adaptiveResize();
            $keepFrame  = $this->keepFrame();
            $keepAspectRatio= $this->keepAspectRatio();
            $constrainOnly  = $this->constrainOnly();
            $imageRealPath = $width.'x'.$height;
            $options = "";

            if(!$keepAspectRatio) {
                $imageRealPath .= '-exact';
            }
            else {
                if(!$keepFrame && $width && $height && ($adaptive !== false)) {
                    $adaptive = strtolower(trim($adaptive));
                    if(isset($this->_adaptiveResizePositions[$adaptive])) {
                        $imageRealPath .= '-'.$adaptive;
                    }
                }
            }
            if($keepFrame) {
                $imageRealPath .= '-frame';
                $_backgroundColor = $this->backgroundColor();
                if($_backgroundColor) {
                    $imageRealPath .= '-'.implode('-',$_backgroundColor);
                }
            }
            if(!$constrainOnly) {
                $imageRealPath .= '-zoom';
            }
        }
        return $imageRealPath;
    }

    protected function _getDestinationPath() {
        if(!$this->_image) {
            return $this;
        }
        if($this->_scheduledResize) {
            return $this->getImageBaseDir().DS.$this->_resizeFolderName.DS.$this->_getDestinationImagePrefix().DS.$this->_image;
        } else {
            return $this->getImageBaseDir().DS.$this->_image;
        }
    }
    protected function _getImageUrl() {
        if(!$this->_image) {
            return false;
        }
        if($this->_scheduledResize) {
            return  $this->getImageBaseUrl().'/'.$this->_resizeFolderName.'/'.$this->_getDestinationImagePrefix().$this->_image;
        }
        else {
           return  $this->getImageBaseUrl().$this->_image;
        }
    }
    protected function _doResize() {
        if(!$this->_image || !$this->_scheduledResize || $this->_resized) {
            return $this;
        }
        $this->_resized = true; //mark as resized
        $width = $this->_width;
        $height = $this->_height;
        $adaptive = $width && $height &&
                    $this->keepAspectRatio() && !$this->keepFrame() &&
                    ($this->adaptiveResize() !== false);
        $adaptivePosition = false;
        if($adaptive) {
            $adaptive = strtolower(trim($this->adaptiveResize()));
            if(isset($this->_adaptiveResizePositions[$adaptive])) {
                $adaptivePosition = $this->_adaptiveResizePositions[$adaptive];
            }
        }
        $processor = $this->_getImageProcessor();

        if(!$adaptivePosition) {
            $processor->resize($width, $height);
            return $this;
        }
        //make adaptive resize
        //https://github.com/wearefarm/magento-adaptive-resize/blob/master/README.md
        $currentRatio = $processor->getOriginalWidth() / $processor->getOriginalHeight();
        $targetRatio  = $width / $height;
        if ($targetRatio > $currentRatio) {
            $processor->resize($width, null);
        }
        else {
            $processor->resize(null, $height);
        }
        $diffWidth  = $processor->getOriginalWidth() - $width;
        $diffHeight = $processor->getOriginalHeight() - $height;
        if($diffWidth || $diffHeight) {
            $processor->crop(
                floor($diffHeight * $adaptivePosition[0]), //top rate
                floor($diffWidth / 2),
                ceil($diffWidth / 2),
                ceil($diffHeight *  $adaptivePosition[1]) //bottom rate
            );
        }
        return $this;
    }
    public function __toString(){
        try{
            if(!$this->_image) {
                throw new Exception($this->_openError);
            }
            $imageRealPath = $this->_getDestinationPath();
            if (!file_exists($imageRealPath)) {
                $this->_doResize();
                $this->_getImageProcessor()->save($imageRealPath);
            }
            return $this->_getImageUrl();
        }
        catch (Exception $e){
            Mage::logException($e);
            return 'data:image/png;base64,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';
        }
    }
}
```

`app/code/local/Easylife/News/Helper/Article/Image.php` - article image helper

```
<?php 
class Easylife_News_Helper_Article_Image
    extends Easylife_News_Helper_Image_Abstract {
    protected $_placeholder = 'images/placeholder/article.jpg';
    protected $_subdir      = 'article';
}
```

Done with the helpers. See part 6

Comment: I think you have your class names wrong for the Image Abstract. You have declared the class as `Easylife_News_Helper_Image_Abstract` but you say add this to path `app/code/local/Easylife/News/Helper/Article/Image/Abstract.php`

Comment: @PanPipes thanks for the heads up. i fixed it

Comment: just spotted a typo in `Easylife_News_Helper_Image_Abstract` you misspelt width on `$this->_width = null;` in `init`

Answer (score 6):

**Part 6**

`app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/easylife_news.xml` -

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout>
    <adminhtml_news_article_index>
        <reference name="menu">
            <action method="setActive">
                <menupath>cms/easylife_news/article</menupath>
            </action>
        </reference>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="easylife_news/adminhtml_article" name="article">
                <block type="adminhtml/store_switcher" name="store_switcher" as="store_switcher">
                    <action method="setUseConfirm"><params>0</params></action>
                </block>
            </block>

        </reference>
    </adminhtml_news_article_index>
    <adminhtml_news_article_grid>
        <block type="core/text_list" name="root" output="toHtml">
            <block type="easylife_news/adminhtml_article_grid" name="article_grid"/>
        </block>
    </adminhtml_news_article_grid>
    <!-- Article add/edit action -->
    <adminhtml_news_article_edit>
        <update handle="editor"/>
        <reference name="menu">
            <action method="setActive">
                <menupath>cms/easylife_news/article</menupath>
            </action>
        </reference>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="easylife_news/adminhtml_article_edit" name="article_edit"></block>
        </reference>
        <reference name="left">
            <block type="adminhtml/store_switcher" name="store_switcher" before="-"></block>
            <block type="easylife_news/adminhtml_article_edit_tabs" name="article_tabs"></block>
        </reference>
        <reference name="head">
            <action method="setCanLoadTinyMce"><load>1</load></action>
        </reference>
        <reference name="js">
            <block type="core/template" name="catalog.wysiwyg.js" template="catalog/wysiwyg/js.phtml"/>
        </reference>
    </adminhtml_news_article_edit>

    <adminhtml_news_article_attribute_index>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="easylife_news/adminhtml_article_attribute" name="attribute_grid"></block>
        </reference>
    </adminhtml_news_article_attribute_index>
    <adminhtml_news_article_attribute_edit>
        <reference name="left">
            <block type="easylife_news/adminhtml_article_attribute_edit_tabs" name="attribute_edit_tabs"></block>
        </reference>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="easylife_news/adminhtml_article_attribute_edit" name="attribute_edit_content"></block>
        </reference>
        <reference name="js">
            <block type="adminhtml/template" name="attribute_edit_js" template="easylife_news/attribute/js.phtml">
                <action method="setMainEntityName"><name>article</name></action>
            </block>
        </reference>
    </adminhtml_news_article_attribute_edit>
</layout>
```

`app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/easylife_news.xml` - the frontend layout file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout>

    <easylife_news_article_index translate="label" module="easylife_news">
        <label>Articles list</label>
        <update handle="page_two_columns_left" />
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="easylife_news/article_list" name="article_list" template="easylife_news/article/list.phtml" />
        </reference>
    </easylife_news_article_index>
    <easylife_news_article_view translate="label" module="easylife_news">
        <label>Article view page</label>
        <update handle="page_two_columns_left" />
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="easylife_news/article_view" name="article_view" template="easylife_news/article/view.phtml" />
        </reference>
    </easylife_news_article_view>
    <easylife_news_article_rss translate="label" module="easylife_news">
        <label>Articles rss feed</label>
        <block type="easylife_news/article_rss" output="toHtml" name="easylife_news.article.rss" />
    </easylife_news_article_rss>
    <rss_index_index>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="easylife_news/rss" name="news.rss" template="easylife_news/rss.phtml">
                <action method="addFeed" ifconfig="easylife_news/article/rss" translate="label" module="easylife_news">
                    <label>Articles</label>
                    <url helper="easylife_news/article/getRssUrl" />
                </action>
            </block>
        </reference>
    </rss_index_index>
</layout>
```

Now the **templates**

`app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/easylife_news/grid.phtml` - grid template

```
<div class="content-header">
<table cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
        <td style="width:50%;"><h3 class="icon-head <?php echo $this->getHeadClass();?>"><?php echo $this->getHeaderText(); ?></h3></td>
        <td class="a-right">
            <?php echo $this->getButtonsHtml() ?>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</div>
<?php if( !Mage::app()->isSingleStoreMode() ): ?>
    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('store_switcher');?>
<?php endif;?>
<div>
    <?php echo $this->getGridHtml() ?>
</div>
```

`app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/easylife_news/form/renderer/fieldset/element.phtml` - fieldset element renderer (used for checkboxes for different store views)

```
<?php $_element = $this->getElement() ?>
<?php $this->checkFieldDisable() ?>

<?php if ($_element->getType()=='hidden'): ?>
<tr>
    <td class="hidden" colspan="100"><?php echo trim($_element->getElementHtml()) ?></td>
</tr>
<?php else: ?>
<tr>
    <td class="label"><?php echo trim($this->getElementLabelHtml()) ?></td>
    <td class="value">
        <?php echo trim($this->getElementHtml()) ?>
        <?php if ($_element->getNote()) : ?>
            <p class="note"><?php echo $_element->getNote() ?></p>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </td>
    <td class="scope-label"><span class="nobr"><?php echo $this->getScopeLabel() ?></span></td>
    <?php if ($this->canDisplayUseDefault()): ?>
    <td class="value use-default">
        <input <?php if($_element->getReadonly()):?> disabled="disabled"<?php endif; ?> type="checkbox" name="use_default[]" id="<?php echo $_element->getHtmlId() ?>_default"<?php if ($this->usedDefault()): ?> checked="checked"<?php endif; ?> onclick="toggleValueElements(this, this.parentNode.parentNode)" value="<?php echo $this->getAttributeCode() ?>"/>
        <label for="<?php echo $_element->getHtmlId() ?>_default" class="normal"><?php echo Mage::helper('easylife_news')->__('Use Default Value') ?></label>
    </td>
    <?php endif; ?>
</tr>
<?php endif; ?>
```

`app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/easylife_news/attribute/js.phtml` - some js required for managing the add/edit attribute form

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
function saveAndContinueEdit(){
    disableElements('save');
    var activeTab = <?php echo $this->getMainEntityName()?>_attribute_tabsJsTabs.activeTab.id;
    if (editForm.submit($('edit_form').action+'back/edit/tab/' + activeTab) == false) {
        enableElements('save');
     }
    varienGlobalEvents.attachEventHandler('formValidateAjaxComplete', function (){
        enableElements('save');
    });
}

function saveAttribute(){
    disableElements('save');
    if (editForm.submit() == false){
        enableElements('save');
    }
    varienGlobalEvents.attachEventHandler('formValidateAjaxComplete', function (){
        enableElements('save');
    });
}

function toggleApplyVisibility(select) {
    if ($(select).value == 1) {
        $(select).next('select').removeClassName('no-display');
        $(select).next('select').removeClassName('ignore-validate');

    } else {
        $(select).next('select').addClassName('no-display');
        $(select).next('select').addClassName('ignore-validate');
        var options = $(select).next('select').options;
        for( var i=0; i < options.length; i++) {
            options[i].selected = false;
        }
    }
}

function checkOptionsPanelVisibility(){
    if($('matage-options-panel')){
        var panel = $('matage-options-panel');
        if($('frontend_input') && ($('frontend_input').value=='select' || $('frontend_input').value=='multiselect')){
            panel.show();
        }
        else {
            panel.hide();
        }
    }
}

function bindAttributeInputType()
{
    checkOptionsPanelVisibility();
    switchDefaultValueField();
    checkIsConfigurableVisibility();
    if($('frontend_input') && ($('frontend_input').value=='select' || $('frontend_input').value=='multiselect' || $('frontend_input').value=='price')){
        if($('is_filterable') && !$('is_filterable').getAttribute('readonly')){
            $('is_filterable').disabled = false;
        }
        if($('is_filterable_in_search') && !$('is_filterable_in_search').getAttribute('readonly')){
            $('is_filterable_in_search').disabled = false;
        }
        if($('backend_type') && $('backend_type').options){
            for(var i=0;i<$('backend_type').options.length;i++){
                if($('backend_type').options[i].value=='int') $('backend_type').selectedIndex = i;
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        if($('is_filterable')){
            $('is_filterable').selectedIndex=0;
            $('is_filterable').disabled = true;
        }
        if($('is_filterable_in_search')){
            $('is_filterable_in_search').disabled = true;
        }
    }

    if ($('frontend_input') && ($('frontend_input').value=='multiselect'
        || $('frontend_input').value=='gallery'
        || $('frontend_input').value=='textarea')) {
        if ($('used_for_sort_by')) {
            $('used_for_sort_by').disabled = true;
        }
    }
    else {
        if ($('used_for_sort_by') && !$('used_for_sort_by').getAttribute('readonly')) {
            $('used_for_sort_by').disabled = false;
        }
    }

    setRowVisibility('is_wysiwyg_enabled', false);
    if ($('frontend_input').value=='textarea') {
        setRowVisibility('is_wysiwyg_enabled', true);
        $('frontend_class').value = '';
        $('frontend_class').disabled = true;
    }
    else if($('frontend_input').value=='text'){
        if (!$('frontend_class').getAttribute('readonly')) {
            $('frontend_class').disabled = false;
        }
    }
    else{
        $('frontend_class').value = '';
        $('frontend_class').disabled = true;
    }

    switchIsFilterable();
}

function switchIsFilterable()
{
    if ($('is_filterable')) {
        if ($('is_filterable').selectedIndex == 0) {
            $('position').disabled = true;
        } else {
            if (!$('position').getAttribute('readonly')){
                $('position').disabled = false;
            }
        }
    }
}

function switchDefaultValueField()
{
    if (!$('frontend_input')) {
        return;
    }

    var currentValue = $('frontend_input').value;

    var defaultValueTextVisibility = false;
    var defaultValueTextareaVisibility = false;
    var defaultValueDateVisibility = false;
    var defaultValueYesnoVisibility = false;
    var scopeVisibility = true;

    switch (currentValue) {
        case 'select':
            optionDefaultInputType = 'radio';
            break;

        case 'multiselect':
            optionDefaultInputType = 'checkbox';
            break;

        case 'date':
            defaultValueDateVisibility = true;
            break;

        case 'boolean':
            defaultValueYesnoVisibility = true;
            break;

        case 'textarea':
            defaultValueTextareaVisibility = true;
            break;

        case 'image':
            defaultValueTextVisibility = false;
            break;
        case 'file':
            defaultValueTextVisibility = false;
            break;
        default:
            defaultValueTextVisibility = true;
            break;
    }


    switch (currentValue) {
        case 'image':
        case 'file':
            $('front_fieldset').previous().hide();
            $('front_fieldset').hide();

            setRowVisibility('is_required', false);
            setRowVisibility('is_unique', false);
            setRowVisibility('frontend_class', false);
        break;

        <?php foreach (Mage::helper('catalog')->getAttributeHiddenFields() as $type=>$fields): ?>
            case '<?php echo $type; ?>':
                <?php foreach ($fields as $one): ?>
                    <?php if ($one == '_front_fieldset'): ?>
                        $('front_fieldset').previous().hide();
                        $('front_fieldset').hide();
                    <?php elseif ($one == '_default_value'): ?>
                        defaultValueTextVisibility =
                        defaultValueTextareaVisibility =
                        defaultValueDateVisibility =
                        defaultValueYesnoVisibility = false;
                    <?php elseif ($one == '_scope'): ?>
                        scopeVisibility = false;
                    <?php else: ?>
                        setRowVisibility('<?php echo $one; ?>', false);
                    <?php endif; ?>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            break;
        <?php endforeach; ?>

        default:
            $('front_fieldset').previous().show();
            $('front_fieldset').show();
            setRowVisibility('is_required', true);
            setRowVisibility('is_unique', true);
            setRowVisibility('frontend_class', true);
            setRowVisibility('is_configurable', true);
        break;
    }

    setRowVisibility('default_value_text', defaultValueTextVisibility);
    setRowVisibility('default_value_textarea', defaultValueTextareaVisibility);
    setRowVisibility('default_value_date', defaultValueDateVisibility);
    setRowVisibility('default_value_yesno', defaultValueYesnoVisibility);
    setRowVisibility('is_global', scopeVisibility);

    var elems = document.getElementsByName('default[]');
    for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
        elems[i].type = optionDefaultInputType;
    }
}

function setRowVisibility(id, isVisible)
{
    if ($(id)) {
        var td = $(id).parentNode;
        var tr = $(td.parentNode);

        if (isVisible) {
            tr.show();
        } else {
            tr.blur();
            tr.hide();
        }
    }
}

function checkIsConfigurableVisibility()
{
    if (!$('is_configurable') || !$('is_global') || !$('frontend_input')) return;
    if ($F('is_global')==1 && $F('frontend_input')=='select') {
        setRowVisibility('is_configurable', true);
    } else {
        setRowVisibility('is_configurable', false);
    }
}

function updateRequriedOptions()
{
    if ($F('frontend_input')=='select' && $F('is_required')==1) {
        $('option-count-check').addClassName('required-options-count');
    } else {
        $('option-count-check').removeClassName('required-options-count');
    }
}

if($('frontend_input')){
    Event.observe($('frontend_input'), 'change', updateRequriedOptions);
    Event.observe($('frontend_input'), 'change', bindAttributeInputType);
    Event.observe($('is_global'), 'change', checkIsConfigurableVisibility);
}

if ($('is_filterable')) {
    Event.observe($('is_filterable'), 'change', switchIsFilterable);
}

if ($('is_required')) {
    Event.observe($('is_required'), 'change', updateRequriedOptions);
}
bindAttributeInputType();
//]]>
</script>
```

`app/design/frontend/base/default/template/easylife_news/article/list.phtml` - frontend list template - may require some styling

```
<?php echo $this->getMessagesBlock()->getGroupedHtml() ?>
<?php $_articles = $this->getArticles(); ?>
<div class="page-title article-title">
    <?php if(Mage::helper('easylife_news/article')->isRssEnabled()) : ?>
        <a href="<?php echo Mage::helper('easylife_news/article')->getRssUrl();?>" class="link-rss"><?php echo Mage::helper('easylife_news')->__('Subscribe to RSS Feed')?></a>
    <?php endif;?>
    <h1><?php echo Mage::helper('easylife_news')->__('Articles') ?></h1>
</div>
<?php if ($_articles->getSize() > 0) :?>
    <?php echo $this->getPagerHtml(); ?>
    <div class="article-list-container">
    <?php foreach ($_articles as $_article) : ?>
        <div class="article-list-item">
            <a href="<?php echo $_article->getArticleUrl()?>">
                <?php echo $_article->getTitle();?>
            </a><br />
        </div>
    <?php endforeach;?>
    </div>
    <?php echo $this->getPagerHtml(); ?>
<?php else : ?>
    <?php echo Mage::helper('easylife_news')->__('There are no articles at this moment');?>
<?php endif;?>
```

`app/design/frontend/base/default/template/easylife_news/article/view.phtml` - frontend view template - may require some styling

```
<?php $_article = $this->getCurrentArticle();?>
<?php echo $this->getMessagesBlock()->getGroupedHtml() ?>
<div class="page-title article-title">
    <h1><?php echo $_article->getTitle(); ?></h1>
</div>
<div class="article-view">
    <div class="article-title">
        <?php echo Mage::helper('easylife_news')->__('Title');?>:<?php echo $_article->getTitle();?>

    </div>
    <div class="article-short_description">
        <?php echo Mage::helper('easylife_news')->__('Short description');?>:<?php echo $_article->getShortDescription();?>

    </div>
    <div class="article-description">
        <?php echo Mage::helper('easylife_news')->__('Description');?>:<?php echo $_article->getDescription();?>

    </div>
    <div class="article-publish_date">
        <?php echo Mage::helper('easylife_news')->__("Publish Date");?>: <?php echo Mage::helper('core')->formatDate($_article->getPublishDate(), 'full');?>

    </div>

</div>
```

`app/design/frontend/base/default/template/easylife_news/rss.php` - rss template

```
<?php $_feeds = $this->getFeeds();?>
<?php if ($_feeds): ?>
<table class="data-table rss-table" id="rss-table-news" style="margin-top:20px">
    <col />
    <col width="1" />
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th colspan="2"><?php echo Mage::helper('easylife_news')->__('News Feeds') ?></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php foreach ($_feeds as $_feed): ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $_feed->getLabel() ?></td>
            <td><a href="<?php echo $_feed->getUrl() ?>" class="link-rss"><?php echo Mage::helper('easylife_news')->__('Get Feed'); ?></a></td>
        </tr>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Now you need to add a placeholder image in case you plan to use image attributes.
The image should be placed in `skin/frontend/base/default/images/placeholder/article.jpg`. Just copy the default magento logo and place it there.

That's it. Simple, right?

Comment: Thankyou Marius.