# Eav_Model and Widget_Form

Tags: blocks, model, forms, eav, widgets

What is the quickest way to render the attributes of a `Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Abstract` in `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form`?

Comment: Check this: http://magento.stackexchange.com/q/22367/146. The answer that starts with 'part 3' might help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Marius's advice I solved my problem in this way.

In `_prepareForm()` of class that extends `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form` I do this operation:

```
protected function _prepareForm() {
    $identify=1;
    $dataModel=Mage::getModel('namespace_module/modelName')->load($identify);

    $form = new Varien_Data_Form();
    $form->setDataObject($dataModel);
    $fieldset = $form->addFieldset('dataModelform',
        array(
            'legend'=>Mage::helper('namespace_module')->__('Name of Fieldset'),
            'class'=>'fieldset-wide',
        )
    );

    $attributes = Mage::getResourceModel('eav/entity_attribute_collection')
        ->setEntityTypeFilter($dataModel->getEntityTypeId());
    foreach ($attributes as $attribute) {
        $attribute->setEntity(Mage::getResourceModel('namespace_module/modelName'));
    }
    $this->_setFieldset($attributes, $fieldset, array());

    $formValues = $setting->getData();
    $form->addValues($formValues);
    $form->setFieldNameSuffix('dataModelElement');
    $this->setForm($form);
}
```