# how to call custom model

Tags: magento-1.7

How can I call model in a custom module? I have a module and I want to create new model in that and use function from model to controller.
my model structure is

```
local>Mypackage>Myenquiry>Model>Mysql4>Myenquiry>Collection.php
```

There is function colletion in Collection.php. I want to call that function in my controller.But i don't know how to declare this model in config file and how to call it in controller

Answer (score 1):

Not entirely sure on the bigger picture here but to call a function from your model, you need to declare your module's model in your config.xml:

```
<config>
<modules>
    <Mypackage_Myenquiry>
        <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Mypackage_Myenquiry>
</modules>
<global>
    ...
    <models>
        <myenquiry>
            <class>Namespace_Module_Model</class>
        </myenquiry>
    </models>
    ...
<global>
```

One you've declared your model you can then call it in any file like so:

```
Mage::getModel('myenquiry/myenquiry')->functionName();
```

From your question it sounds as though your creating your own entity and are wanting to get a collection of that entity, in this case i'm not sure how far you have gotten but you should take a look at some of the following posts/walkthroughs:

[Smashing Magazine - How to create an Admin Manageable Entity...](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2014/03/tutorial-create-admin-manageable-magento-entity-brands/)

[Inchoo - Creating EAV based Model(s) in Magento](http://inchoo.net/magento/creating-an-eav-based-models-in-magento/)

[How to create an EAV entity](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/22367/how-to-create-an-eav-entity)

Hope this helps,

Josh

Answer (score 0):

You can call Model, like :

```
//Creating Model instance
$enquiryModel = Mage::getModel("myenquiry/myenquiry");
//Calling Model's function
$enquiryModel->yourFunctionName();
```

For creating Model, you have to declare it in `config.xml`, like:

```
<global>
    <!-- ... -->
    <models>
        <myenquiry>
            <class>Mypackage_Myenquiry_Model</class>
            <!--
            if want to create own resource, use below line.
            Default is core_resource
            -->
            <resourceModel>myenquiry_resource</resourceModel>
        </myenquiry>
    </models>
    <!-- ... -->
</global>
```

For more about Models, check here : [Create Custom Model](http://www.pixafy.com/blog/2013/04/creating-a-magento-custom-model/)