# Magento 2 : EAV Tutorial Needed

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-2.1, module, eav

In magento 1.9 I created a custom module with EAV models with the help of following tutorial.
[How to create an EAV entity?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/22367/how-to-create-an-eav-entity)

Is there any equivalent in magento 2.

Comment: Did you find any solution for this ? if any thing please share here. bcz even i am lokking for the same. thanks

Comment: Not yet, I wanted to have an interface in backend to add /edit attribute like we do for products. In mage 1.9, I had done it with the help of above mentioned tutorial, but in magento 2.1, I did not find any such tutorial.

Answer (score 2):

Eav attributes can be made for a lot of different things. Products is one of them. So when you search for that you want to include what you are making them for.

You also have custom attributes which is something else.

Best documentation here is from Magento self :

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/extension-dev-guide/attributes.html

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/ui_comp_guide/howto/add_category_attribute.html